# Python rounding problem

Tags: python, math, floating-point

```
>>> num = 4.123456
>>> round(num, 3) # expecting 4.123
4.1230000000000002
```

I'm expecting 4.123 as a result, Am I wrong?

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly

Comment: Also very related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary

Comment: It's a FAQ:

http://www.python.org/doc/faq/general/#why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an *exact* representation of your floating point number, you have to use [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Decimal is in general no more exact than binary floating point. It can represent *decimal* fractions exactly (up to a point), which is of course the entire point of the data type, but it also has its limitations.

Comment: `decimal.Decimal` has both representation and roundoff errors, just like `float`, though you can control them some additional ways. I have yet to see a case where someone's problem of float inexactness had the best solution of using `Decimal` instead. `Decimal` is mostly useful in niche financial applications.

Comment: @Joren: *Compared to the built-in float implementation of binary floating point, the new class is especially helpful for financial applications and other uses which require **exact decimal representation**, control over precision, control over rounding to meet legal or regulatory requirements, tracking of significant decimal places, or for applications where the user expects the results to match calculations done by hand.* from [this book](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/DecimalFloatingPointArithmetic.html). Maybe my answer is not well phrased but this is what I meant.

Comment: "Exact decimal representations" (which slightly oversells `decimal.Decimal` to start with) is a lot different than "*exact* floating point numbers". The key phrase in that quote is "helpful for financial applications".

Comment: @Felix: What Mike says. For what it's worth, that downvote wasn't mine, I think your suggestion can be helpful for dealing with the OP's problem. But I needed to remark that 'exact floating point' is misleading. Decimal floating point will not represent, for example, 1/3 exactly. For that you'd need to have ternary floating point. There is an infinite amount of other fractions decimal floating point can't represent exactly.

Comment: @Joren: Ok. I have to confess I am not that much into floating point numbers so my wording was probably wrong. Sorry for that. Anyway, as you said, this module might help the OP with his problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a mistake. You need to read What Every computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic:

http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 6):

Yep, your expectations don't match the design intent of your tools.

Check out [this section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) of the Python tutorial.

---

Using `math.round` is actually pretty rare. if you're trying to display a number as a string to a certain precision, you might want something more like

```
>>> num = 4.123456
>>> print "%.3f" % num
4.123
```

You might be interested in the documentation on [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Comment: I'm finding the canon floating point page over-linked. The link you gave in Python docs is way more practical, and on a level most people can understand and appreciate.

Comment: Both are valuable resources. I agree this one is a lot better for beginners, but eventually people will want to read the Goldberg article as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to get that as a number, not string.

Comment: @pocoa, What is wrong with `4.1230000000000002`? If you think `decimal.Decimal` is the answer, you are most likely not understanding the situation well enough.

Comment: maybe you're right. I just wanted to store the first 3 digits. I could have the same effect with doing string formatting when displaying it. I was just confused.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you care?  (That's a serious question.)

The answer that you're getting is so close to `4.123` as to make no difference.  It can't be exactly `4.123`, since there are only finitely many numbers (around `2**64` on a typical machine) that Python can represent exactly, and without going into detail about floating-point representations, it just so happens that `4.123` isn't one of those numbers. By the way, `4.1230000000000002` isn't one of the numbers that can be exactly represented, either;  the actual number stored is `4.12300000000000022026824808563105762004852294921875`, but Python truncates the decimal representation to 17 significant digits for display purposes.  So:

1. If you're doing mathematics with the result, then the difference between `4.123` and what you're getting is so tiny as to make no real difference.  Just don't worry about it.
2. If you just care about the output looking pretty (i.e., what you're after here is a string rather than a number) then use `str`, or string formatting.
3. In the unlikely case that the difference really does matter, e.g., because you're doing financial work and this affects the direction that something rounds later on, use the `decimal` module.

Final note: In Python 3.x and Python 2.7, the `repr` of a float has changed so that you will actually get `4.123` as you expect here.

Comment: +1, "If you're doing mathematics with the result, then the difference between `4.123` and what you're getting is so tiny as to make no real difference." <--- exactly

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thank you guys for making me understand/remember that.