# Round fractional part of a float

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I am trying to round up the right hand side (fractional part) of a float.

I want to round it up to 5

```
x = 0.43
```

expected outcome

```
0.45
```

I can convert the float into an int and then split the string by "." and then round the right hand side of the decimal point but I dont think this is the best method available.

Is there a function available for this type of task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you the desired output.

```
def round_to(n, precision=0.5):
    correction = 0.5 if n >= 0 else -0.5
    return int(n/precision+correction)*precision
```

If you call it:

```
>>> round_to(0.43)
0.45
```

I got this function from [Python - Round to nearest 05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265546/python-round-to-nearest-05)

Comment: Can this handle something like 0.06? I would want that round up to 0.10 but I'm guessing this func will round it to 0.00

Comment: If you call this as `round_to(0.06)`, it will return `0.05`, as that is the nearest `0.05`, but if you call it as `round_to(0.06, 0.10)`, it will return `0.1`