# Number changing when inserted into list

Tags: python, list, floating-point, python-2.x

I'm only going to paste part of my code since it's very long, but I was wondering if any one might know potential causes of this problem. So I have this code here:

```
print "part a", working_weight
cells[working_cell_position][4] = working_weight
print "part b", working_weight, cells[working_cell_position][4], cells[working_cell_position]
```

and what it prints is this:

```
part a 62.4
part b 62.4 62.4 [6, 6, '', '', 62.400000000000006]
```

So if you didn't quite get it, basically I have the variable `working_weight` which is `62.4`, but when I insert it into a list, it changes it to `62.400000000000006`, yet if I only print that number from the list it prints as `62.4` still. If anyone could help, or suggest a solution to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986150/python-floating-number

Comment: Unfortunately, the question marked as a duplicate doesn't really answer this either.  The reason for the *difference* between the two displays is that Python 2.x has *two* distinct built-in ways for formatting a float: `str`, which rounds to 12 significant figures, and `repr`, which prints as many digits as are needed to represent the value faithfully.  `print` applied to a float by itself uses the `str`, while `print` of a list applies the `repr` to each item.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `float`s are inherently imprecise in pretty much every language, as they cannot be represented easily in 64-bit binary at the lowest level.  What is happening to your code has nothing to do with how it is put into the `list` or anything like that.

If you want to keep a precise decimal you should use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html).

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> working_weight = Decimal(str(working_weight))
>>> working_weight
Decimal('62.4')
```

This `Decimal` can then have operations performed on it like any `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is tough, that's the problem. If you have decimals, use [`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/decimal.html).

```
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal("30")
b = Decimal("32.4")
print(a+b)
# Decimal ('62.4')
```

Comment: What is the point of this answer when my answer was present first with the same idea?

Comment: @AlexThornton A better question would be, why bother answering this at all, instead of finding one of the countless possible duplicates of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without having a reproducible problem, but one way to get something similar is for example

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([62.4], numpy.float)
print a[0]      # outputs 62.4
print [a[0]]    # outputs [62.399999999999999]
```

where is `working_height` coming from? What is `working_height.__class__`?