# Sum of floats: unexpected result

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, digit

The following output surprised me:

```
1.1 + 2.2
=> 3.3000000000000003
```

An unexpected small digit came up from the sum. The same does not happen for other addends, e.g.:

```
3.0 + 0.3
=> 3.3
```

I tried both in Python 2.7 and in 3.4, but the result is the same. What is the reason for this unexpected result of the sum?

Comment: I think the [docs mention this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: A must read: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2):

Mainly because binary doesn't play well with decimal (2 and 10 are coprime) and floats have limited precision.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, when it comes down to it, computers are working with binary numbers.  Some fractional numbers do not translate as neat as we would like to binary numbers.  The resulting value includes some left-over digital garbage.

Answer (score 1):

For a more complete discussion, see: [python floating number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986150/python-floating-number) and [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points) but a reasonable solution might be to specify the desired precision like:

```
>>> a = 1.1 + 2.2
>>> a = round(a,1)
>>> a 
3.3
```