# Truncate a decimal value in Python

Tags: python, formatting, decimal, truncate

I am trying to truncate a decimal value in Python. I don't want to round it, but instead just display the decimal values upto the specified accuracy. I tried the following:

```
d = 0.989434
'{:.{prec}f}'.format(d, prec=2)
```

This rounds it to 0.99. But I actually want the output to be 0.98. Obviously, `round()` is not an option. Is there any way to do this? Or should I go back to the code and change everything to `decimal`?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm not sure if there is a way to do this with string formatting. I'll do some research :)

Comment: More answers please. We definitely need more.

Comment: This is not a `decimal.Decimal`, but a `float`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of all your requirements, but this will be fairly robust.

```
>> before_dec, after_dec = str(d).split('.')
>> float('.'.join((before_dec, after_dec[0:2])))
0.98
```

#### 2018-01-03 edit

This answer isn't robust or mathematically correct. See [Nilani Algiriyage's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545023/328501) for the correct way to do this using `Decimal.quantize` method.

Comment: `after_dec[:2]` is enough :)

Comment: It sure is, but I believe that convention makes more sense in the case where the the other side is unknown, i.e. `a_list[3:]` so I don't really pay much attention to `[0:2]` vs `[:2]`, whichever comes out at the time is good enough :)

Comment: Why did you accept this as the solution? :) I would find some of the math based solutions slightly more robust!

Comment: @James Mills The only not robust part is if there is no decimal place, and surely you can figure out how to deal with that :)

Comment: Just curious is all :) I would use the ``Decimal`` or any of the other math-based solutions personally! *I totally forgot that floating-point string formatting specifiers do rounding!* :/

Comment: Yeah, I am curious of the OP's opinion too, but if I were to guess, the math makes it harder to understand and is not necessary for this case.

Comment: if i were to guess: he probably just wanted to do this on only one number, and as soon as he got a working solution he accepted it, without bothering to read the others...

Comment: @JamesMills to be frank, my browser didn't update with your solution when I accepted Derek's solution..also, Derek's solution was pretty straightforward and is more than enough in the particular instance I am working on...

Comment: @Kraay89 not exactly...blame it on IE for not loading the page...:-)

Comment: My solution was incorrect anyway, so that doesn't matter. All good!

Comment: Thanks to all of you...:-)

Comment: @user295338 i'm sorry. Your generic name made me jump to conclusions (i'll go wash my mouth now)

Comment: @Kraay89 No probs...I was also bit hasty in closing this question (wanted to get home early :-))

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer comes up as the top answer in Google for this question. `decimal` has a built-in, mathematically-correct way to do this, and Nilani Algiriyage's answer shows how.

Answer (score 17):

You can use following code

```
import decimal
d = 0.989434

print decimal.Decimal(d).quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_DOWN)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
d = 0.989434
print floor(d * 100) / 100
```

> Math.floor(x) Return the floor of x as a float, the largest integer
>   value less than or equal to x.

Moving the 2 decimals on the left of the decimal '.', flooring, then moving back the numbers on the right of the '.'

100 can be modifying by

```
n = 2
m = pow (10, n)
d = 0.989434
print floor(d * m) / m
```

`n` is your wanted precision.

**EDIT:**
In case d is negative, you have to use the ceil method

```
if d < 0:
    print ceil(d * m) / m
else:
    print floor(d * m) / m
```

Comment: Note that for `d = -0.989434` this prints `-0.99`

Answer (score 3):

Format it to something much longer and then cut off the extra digits:

```
def truncate(f, digits):
    return ("{:.30f}".format(f))[:-30+digits]
```

Comment: It's inefficient but the only answer here that doesn't seem to have broken edge-cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
import math

d = 0.989434
prec = 2
output = math.floor(d * (10 ** prec)) / (10 ** prec)
```

If you still want a decimal variable instead of string

Comment: Note that for `d = -0.989434` this prints `-0.99`

Comment: @Eric Yeah you are right! That comes from the definition of `floor`. Seems that better to use string formatting. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way I believe.

1. Move the significant digits to the left
2. Truncate the decimal part
3. Move the number of digits moved to left, to right

   ```
   d = 0.989434
   print "{0:0.2f}".format(int(d * 100)/100.0)
   ```

   **Output**

   ```
   0.98
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Also with math:

```
d = 0.989434
x = int(d * 100.0) / 100.0
print "{0:0.2f}".format(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will print 0.98 in this case, though you'll have to be careful that your d value doesn't become larger than or equal to 10 as then it'll only print, for e.g., 10.1 rather than 10.12.

```
d = 0.989434
print '{:.{prec}s}'.format(str(d), prec=4)
```

Comment: I gives me an error...Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot to change the f to an s in the string formatting. Have edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

with `str`:

```
d = str(0.989434)
print float(d[:d.find('.')+3])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to display you can convert it to string and slice it :

```
d = 0.989434
print str(d)[0:4] #or print(str(d)[0:4])
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly similar to some other answers, but without any imports

```
def truncate(x, d):
    return int(x*(10.0**d))/(10.0**d)

>>>truncate(0.987654, 2)
0.98
```

Comment: Pretty sure `int(x*(10.0**d))/(10.0**d)` would work just as well here

Comment: You are absolutely right! Don't know why i did not see that :P With your permission i'll change or add it to the answer...

Comment: I'm not gonna stop you changing it!

Answer (score 0):

In this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-3-decimals-in-python/46746524#46746524) I posted the solution below:

```
def truncate_number(f_number, n_decimals):
      strFormNum = "{0:." + str(n_decimals+5) + "f}"
      trunc_num = float(strFormNum.format(f_number)[:-5])
      return(trunc_num)

# Testing the 'trunc_num()' function
test_num = 1150/252
[(idx, truncate_number(test_num, idx)) for idx in range(0, 20)]
```

At leat it doesn't require to load any module nor demands new calculations. So far, it solved my problem with the truncation requirements in public bond prices calculations.