# How can I limit to 5 digits a Python variable (float type)?

Tags: python, numpy, numbers

I have the variable

```
current_price = 1.158805
```

But I need to limit to 5 numbers (in this case I want
the current price to be 1.15880), what can I do?

I need a general solution because the variable changes every second.

And what if I have the numer in a pandas dataframe, for example `data.close.iloc[-1]`?

Comment: What if the number is `current_price = 1.1588050`? Or what if you have `0.5`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think it cannot assume 7 digits, but in case that would be fine too for what i need to do. If 0.5 that would be a problem... any idea how to solve?

Comment: What would be fine? What should be the result in these two example?

Comment: I need that 5 digits

Comment: So you don't need to remove the "last" digit, but you need to limit the number to 5 digits?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes exactly, maybe i have to modify my question? (sorry i am new here)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544714/truncate-a-decimal-value-in-python

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe i have to delete my question? What do you think?

Comment: I see no value in keeping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 current_price = 1.158805
 
 print(str(current_price)[:-1])
```

Your output will be:

```
 >>> 1.15880
```