# round down to 2 decimal in python

Tags: python, rounding

I need to round down and it should be two decimal places.
Tried the following,

```
a = 28.266
print round(a, 2)
```

> 28.27

But the expected value is 28.26 only.

Comment: You want to truncate. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-3-decimals-in-python

Comment: @zinjaai is right half of the time if you reference the top answer. However, consider the comment `'%.3f'%(1324343032.3243) and '%.3f'%(1324343032.3245) give different results` This is because the top answer is actually equivalent to rounding. I would just use @Psidom's answer here instead.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Seems like you need the `floor`:

```
import math
math.floor(a * 100)/100.0

# 28.26
```

Answer (score 36):

It seems you want truncation, not rounding.

A simple way would be to combine floor division `//` and regular division `/`:

```py
>>> a = 28.266
>>> a // 0.01 / 100
28.26
```

Instead of the regular division you could also multiply (as noted in the comments by [cmc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187273/cmc)):

```py
>>> a // 0.01 * 0.01
28.26
```

Similarly you could create a function to round down to other more/less decimals. But because floats are inexact numbers, this can lead to inaccuracies.

```py
def round_down(value, decimals):
    factor = 1 / (10 ** decimals)
    return (value // factor) * factor

print(round_down(28.266, 2))
# 28.26
```

But as said it's not exactly exact:

```py
for i in range(0, 8):
    print(i, round_down(12.33333, i))
```

```
0 12.0
1 12.3
2 12.33
3 12.333
4 12.333300000000001 # weird, but almost correct
5 12.33332           # wrong
6 12.33333
7 12.33333
```

There are other (more precise) approaches though:

### A solution using the `fraction` module

A `fraction` can represent a decimal number much more exact than a `float`. Then one can use the "multiply, then floor, then divide" approach mentioned by Psidom but with significantly higher precision:

```py
import fractions
import math

a = 28.266

def round_down(value, decimals):
    factor = 10 ** decimals
    f = fractions.Fraction(value)
    return fractions.Fraction(math.floor(f * factor),  factor)

print(round_down(28.266, 2))
# 1413/50  <- that's 28.26
```

And using the test I did with the floats:

```py
for i in range(0, 8):
    print(i, round_down(12.33333, i))
```

```
0 12
1 123/10
2 1233/100
3 12333/1000
4 123333/10000
5 1233333/100000
6 1233333/100000
7 1233333/100000
```

However creating a `Fraction` will not magically fix an inexact `float`, so typically one should create the `Fraction` from a string or a "numerator-denominator pair" instead of from float.

### A solution using the `decimal` module

You could also use the `decimal` module, which offers a variety of rounding modes, including rounding down.

For this demonstration I'm using a context manager to avoid changing the decimal rounding mode globally:

```py
import decimal

def round_down(value, decimals):
    with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
        d = decimal.Decimal(value)
        ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_DOWN
        return round(d, decimals)

print(round_down(28.266, 2))  # 28.26
```

Which gives more sensible results for the rounding:

```py
for i in range(0, 8):
    print(i, round_down(12.33333, i))
```

```
0 12
1 12.3
2 12.33
3 12.333
4 12.3333
5 12.33333
6 12.333330
7 12.3333300
```

As with `Fraction` a `Decimal` should be created from a string to avoid the intermediate inexact float. But different from `Fraction` the `Decimal` have limited precision, so for values with lots of significant figures it will also become inexact.

However "rounding down" is just one of the available options. The list of [available rounding modes](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes) is extensive:

> ### Rounding modes
>
> `decimal.ROUND_CEILING` Round towards Infinity.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_DOWN` Round towards zero.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_FLOOR` Round towards -Infinity.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN` Round to nearest with ties going towards zero.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN` Round to nearest with ties going to nearest even integer.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` Round to nearest with ties going away from zero.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_UP` Round away from zero.
>
> `decimal.ROUND_05UP` Round away from zero if last digit after rounding towards zero would have been 0 or 5; otherwise round towards zero.

Comment: @user2682863 Some of the solutions mentioned in my example are affected by floating point imprecision. But I noted that on each approach but the last two solutions with fraction and decimal aren't affected.

Answer (score 14):

With Python 3 you can use [`quantize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize)

```
from decimal import *    
>>> Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('7.32')
```

Answer (score 7):

here's a simple function that isn't affected by float precision errors

```
def truncate_float(n, places):
    return int(n * (10 ** places)) / 10 ** places
```

Tests:

```
>>> truncate_float(28.266, 3)
28.266
>>> truncate_float(28.266, 2)
28.26
>>> truncate_float(28.266, 1)
28.2
```

Answer (score 4):

simply try this:

```
import math
a = 28.266
print((math.floor(a * 100)) / 100.0)
```

Output:

```
28.26
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an even simpler way of doing this generically, by subtracting a small quantity before rounding, like so:

```
a = 28.269
digits = 2
print(round(a - 0.5/10**digits, digits))
```

This is based on the intuition that one way of rounding a float to the nearest integer is by adding 0.5, then truncating. The above solution does the opposite by subtracting a half of the minimal 'tick' that the desired precision allows, then rounding.

Comment: If you use `digits = 3` then the result is `28.268` - which isn't correct

Comment: You're right, it's occasionally incorrect for certain values. Is this because round() uses the round half even mode?

Comment: I think the difference is because floats are inexact, `a - 0.5/10**digits` is actually `28.268499999999999516830939683132...` for `digits=3`. However `28.269` is also not exactly representable as float: `28.268999999999998351540853036568...`. That's why my answer also shows how to use `Fraction` or `Decimal` to round the value, because fraction is "really exact" and decimal is almost always "exact enough" (at least if the input is given as string (not as float).

Answer (score 0):

Simple function which you can use in your codes. This function you can also use for integer floor numbers.

```
import math
def floorDecimal(number, decimal):
    return math.floor(number * pow(10, decimal))/pow(10, decimal)
```

Example of using:

```
number = 256.789
newNumber = floorDecimal(number, 2) # newNumber is 256.78
newNumber = floorDecimal(number, -2) # newNumber is 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I use with **f** for the float and **d** for the number of decimals

```
from math import floor

def floor_decimal(f, d):
    n = 10 ** d
    return floor(f * n) / n
```

Answer (score 0):

options for 3 characters, but the difference is only in dividing by 1000 and 100, no math

```py
n = float(input())
print(int(n * 1000) / 1000)
```

or

```py
n = float(input())
print(n * 1000 //1 /1000)
```

or

```py
a=input()
print(float(a[:5])) # if the number of characters is known
```