# Numerical decimal rounding not working correctly in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want keep only 3 decimals of the value which I have in a column. But its not working properly.

**Input Data**

```
td['latitude']    
    2.999852
    2.999852
    2.714852
    4.998789
    4.999789
```

My code

```
dd = round(td['latitude'], 3)
```

**Current Output**

```
dd
3.0
3.0
2.714
5.0
5.0
```

**Expected Output**

```
dd
2.999
2.999
2.714
4.998
4.9997
```

What is wrong in my code. How to fix this.

Comment: Refer below link. Think it will be useful.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383787/round-down-to-2-decimal-in-python

Answer (score 0):

*What is wrong in my code*: `round` is round, i.e. returns the closest integer/precision `round(1.66, 1) = 1.7`.

*How to fix this*: I remembered some question/answer with truncate, but can't find them with a simple search. So here's a quick solution:

```
td['latitude'] // 0.001 * 0.001
```

Output:

```
0    2.999
1    2.999
2    2.714
3    4.998
4    4.999
```

Comment: But will it more than 6  decimal points and also 5 decimal points