# python-Binance api: APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE

Tags: python, binance, cryptocurrency

When trying to place a buy or sell order with the python-binance API I got the following error:

> APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: LOT_SIZE.

Now I've seen at [iceberg_parts](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#iceberg) that this means there is probably something wrong with my buying or selling quantity. I've tried to increase the quantity by a factor 10 but this only gives me another related error:

> APIError(code=-1013): Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL.

Here's some of my code:

```py
diff = current_price - prev_price
if diff <= 0.0001:
    order = client.order_market_buy(symbol = market , quantity = '0.0001')
    print('buy order')
        
if diff >= 0.00040:
    order = client.order_market_sell(symbol =market, quantity ='0.0001')
    print('sell order')
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 19):

This error appears because you are trying to create an order with a quantity lower than the minimun required.

You can access the minimun required of a specific pair with:

```
info = client.get_symbol_info('ETHUSDT')
print(info)
```

Output a dictionary with information about that pair.
Now you can access the minimun quantity required with:

```
print(info['filters'][2]['minQty'])
# 0.00001
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just gone through this same problem. As a noob, some of the code in these answers seem quite complicated so I came up with a solution.

Code:

```
def check_decimals(symbol):
    info = client.get_symbol_info(symbol)
    val = info['filters'][2]['stepSize']
    decimal = 0
    is_dec = False
    for c in val:
        if is_dec is True:
            decimal += 1
        if c == '1':
            break
        if c == '.':
            is_dec = True
    return decimal
```

then when you place the order, just do for ex:
(make sure qty is a float or decimal)

```
  B_order = round(qty / symbol_price, decimal)
  order = client.order_market_buy(
            symbol=symbol_name,
            quantity=B_order)
```

Answer (score 4):

The buying or selling quantity has to be >= 10.3 USD or 10.3/price, pass the quantity and price to these decimal settings/filters with the amounts set with decimal

```
from decimal import Decimal as D, ROUND_DOWN, ROUND_UP
import decimal

info = client.get_symbol_info(symbol=pair)
price_filter = float(info['filters'][0]['tickSize'])
ticker = client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=pair)
price = float(ticker['price'])
price = D.from_float(price).quantize(D(str(price_filter)))
minimum = float(info['filters'][2]['minQty']) # 'minQty'
quant = D.from_float(quantity).quantize(D(str(minimum))) # if quantity >= 10.3/price
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions so that others can understand your answer in future

Comment: Thank you, I posted prematurely please check again.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can explain why the server returns this error.

### Filters

From the endpoint `GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo`, you can find all details regarding the trading symbols. It includes many filters that clients need to follow to place an order. For example, the `BTCUSDT` has the filters as of today(2022-08-31)

```json
"filters": [
    {
        "filterType": "PRICE_FILTER",
        "minPrice": "0.01000000",
        "maxPrice": "1000000.00000000",
        "tickSize": "0.01000000"
    },
    {
        "filterType": "PERCENT_PRICE",
        "multiplierUp": "5",
        "multiplierDown": "0.2",
        "avgPriceMins": 5
    },
    {
        "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
        "minQty": "0.00001000",
        "maxQty": "9000.00000000",
        "stepSize": "0.00001000"
    },
    {
        "filterType": "MIN_NOTIONAL",
        "minNotional": "10.00000000",
        "applyToMarket": true,
        "avgPriceMins": 5
    },
    {
        "filterType": "ICEBERG_PARTS",
        "limit": 10
    },
    {
        "filterType": "MARKET_LOT_SIZE",
        "minQty": "0.00000000",
        "maxQty": "282.39806510",
        "stepSize": "0.00000000"
    },
    {
        "filterType": "TRAILING_DELTA",
        "minTrailingAboveDelta": 10,
        "maxTrailingAboveDelta": 2000,
        "minTrailingBelowDelta": 10,
        "maxTrailingBelowDelta": 2000
    },
    {
        "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ORDERS",
        "maxNumOrders": 200
    },
    {
        "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS",
        "maxNumAlgoOrders": 5
    }
]
```

### LOT_SIZE validation

#### minQty

If you place an order on this `BTCUSDT` with parameters:

```
price=19000
side=BUY
type=LIMIT
quantity=0.000005
```

that is a `LIMIT` `BUY` order with `price` of $19,000, but the `quantity` is less than `minQty` in the `LOT_SIZE`:

0.000005 < 0.00001000

then the server will reject the order, because the request can't pass this filter validation.

---

✗  `LOT_SIZE`.`minQty`

#### stepSize

Can I place an order with the same parameters but only change the `quantity` to 0.000015? That is:

```
price=19000
side=BUY
type=LIMIT
quantity=0.000015
```

You will still receive this error, because the quantity is not able to pass the stepSize size validation: (`quantity`- `minQty`) % `stepSize` == 0

(0.000015 - 0.00001) % 0.00001 != 0

---

✓  `LOT_SIZE`.`minQty`
✗  `LOT_SIZE`.`stepSize`

### MIN_NOTIONAL Validation

Alright, let us change the `quantity` to `0.00002`, with same parameters:

```
price=19000
side=BUY
type=LIMIT
quantity=0.00002
```

The order will still be rejected with a different error because it can't pass the filter `MIN_NOTIONAL` validation.

19000 x 0.00002 = 0.38 < 10 (`MIN_NOTIONAL`.`minNotional`)

Note:

- `minNotional` defines the minimum notional value that required for each order.
- For `MARKET` order, the average price is used over the last `avgPriceMins` minutes.

---

✓  `LOT_SIZE`.`minQty`
✓  `LOT_SIZE`.`stepSize`
✗  `MIN_NOTIONAL`.`minNotional`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code.

```
def round_down(self, coin, number):
    info = self.client.get_symbol_info('%sUSDT' % coin)
    step_size = [float(_['stepSize']) for _ in info['filters'] if _['filterType'] == 'LOT_SIZE'][0]
    step_size = '%.8f' % step_size
    step_size = step_size.rstrip('0')
    decimals = len(step_size.split('.')[1])
    return math.floor(number * 10 ** decimals) / 10 ** decimals
```

Comment: Please explain  the code. Even adding some sample output also helps understanding the code.

Comment: Truncation could be applied using this one line of code: `amount // step_size * step_size` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41383900/1623342)

Answer (score 1):

I have read through all of these forum questions and no one has mentioned the fact that **Binance** charges a **0.1%** fee on all transactions. Meaning you do not have your original buying quantity available to sell back when the sell is triggered.

I have attempted to solve this with:

```py
buy_quantity = round(buy_amount * 0.999, len(str(lotsize).split('.')[1]))
```

Multiplying my original purchase quantity by **0.999** should reduce it by the amount needed to be able to sell it back.

Comment: I am realizing that a much better way to do this would be to use:

free_bal = [i for i in client.get_account()['balances'] if i['asset'] == 'BTC'][0]['free']

Comment: You don't need to comment if you like to change your solution. You can edit it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72961932/edit).

Answer (score 0):

```
https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html

from binance.helpers import round_step_size

# to get a lot size
def getLotSize(self):
    info = self.apiCall(lambda: self.client.get_symbol_info(self.pair))
    lotSize = float(info['filters'][2]['minQty'])
    return lotSize


# get ceiling value and correct format for a lot size
def getCeilingVal(self):
    pairData = self.apiCall(lambda: 
    self.client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol=self.pair))
    pairPrice = pairData["price"]
    ceilingVal = float(self.dInv) / float(pairPrice)

    aLotSize = self.getLotSize()
    rounded_amount = round_step_size(ceilingVal, aLotSize)

    return rounded_amount
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very helpful code using binance-python package

```
  ...
  // Full code: https://github.com/ndiecodes/binance-trading-bot/blob/main/main.py

  def get_round_step_quantity(self, qty):
    info = self.client.get_symbol_info(Config.TRADESYMBOL)
    for x in info["filters"]:
        if x["filterType"] == "LOT_SIZE":
            self.minQty = float(x["minQty"])
            self.maxQty = float(x["maxQty"])
            self.stepSize= float(x["stepSize"])
    if qty < self.minQty:
        qty = self.minQty
    return round_step_size(quantity=qty, step_size=self.stepSize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi adding a bit further to @stack if I've 20 dollars to buy then my quantity would be as below

I've done like below

```
    decimal_places=abs(Decimal(symbl_info['filters'][2]["stepSize"]).normalize().as_tuple().exponent)
print("DECIMAL PLACES {0}".format(decimal_places))
buy_qauntity= round((20/order_input["askPrice"].values[0]),decimal_places)
print(buy_qauntity)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not about `MARKET_LOT_SIZE`. This is `MIN_NOTIONAL`. Let's say `ETHUSDT`'s `minQty` (under `MARKET_LOT_SIZE` filter) is 0.001 but you can still not place an order as notional (under `MIN_NOTIONAL` filter) is 20. Your order value must be above 20 (`MIN_NOTIONAL`) and your qty must over 0.001 (`minQty`). You want to grab these filters via `exchangeInfo`

[Check out docs](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#test-connectivity)

Answer (score -1):

I write a function like that. It's working for me.

```
def getPriceLotFormat(self, priceOrg, quantityOrg):
    price = float(priceOrg)
    quantity = float(quantityOrg)
    response = self.get_symbol_info(car.pair) #self is client btw
    priceFilterFloat = format(float(response["filters"][0]["tickSize"]), '.20f')
    lotSizeFloat = format(float(response["filters"][2]["stepSize"]), '.20f')
    # PriceFilter
    numberAfterDot = str(priceFilterFloat.split(".")[1])
    indexOfOne = numberAfterDot.find("1")
    if indexOfOne == -1:
        price = int(price)
    else:
        price = round(float(price), int(indexOfOne - 1))
    # LotSize
    numberAfterDotLot = str(lotSizeFloat.split(".")[1])
    indexOfOneLot = numberAfterDotLot.find("1")
    if indexOfOneLot == -1:
        quantity = int(quantity)
    else:
        quantity = round(float(quantity), int(indexOfOneLot))
    print(f"""
    ##### SELL #####
    Pair : {str(car.pair)}
    Cash : {str(car.price)}
    Quantity : {str(car.quantity)}
    Price : {str(car.price)}
        """)
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use the Log10 function to get rounding precision from the Binance /api/v3/exchangeinfo endpoint data.

```golang
CurrencyRoundNum = int(math.Abs(math.Log10(stepSize)))
PriceRoundNum = int(math.Abs(math.Log10(tickSize)))
```

The full version on golang is [here](https://gist.github.com/vladimirfilin/59cbab5ce7ebd722a7192f3cacd97d5b), or [at go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/6t2ZREfVe0k). I'm sorry that code is not on python.

Answer (score -1):

So I was struggling with the LOT_SIZE error myself.

Previously I was using the round_step_size function from the python-binance library, however, I had to edit this function to deal with this API error.

Here is a function that I use:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN
import math
from typing import Union

def round_step_size(quantity: Union[float, Decimal], step_size: Union[float, Decimal]) -> float:
    if step_size == 1.0:
        return math.floor(quantity)
    elif step_size < 1.0:
        return Decimal(f'{quantity}').quantize(Decimal(f'{step_size}'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
```