# Binance API sell only the profit & all the position

Tags: php, binance

I'm trying to understand what's the logic to implement when selling only the profit or all the position of a given order.

I have already implemented the BUY operation. So, let's say the user wants to buy 100$ worth of BTC at the current BTC price, I do as the follow:

```
$params = 
[
    'symbol' => 'BTCUSDT', 
    'side' => 'BUY', 
    'type' => 'MARKET', 
    'quoteOrderQty' => 100, 
    'timestamp' => $timestamp
];

$binance->buy($params);
```

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-order-trade

I save both `OrderId` & `clientOrderId` response from Binance. A week later I'd like to sell the order position and to have the following available options:

1. Sell only the profit of this order & (maybe) close
2. Sell all my position (no matter if with profit or not) of this order & (maybe) close

**Question**: How can I accomplish both situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to wait for when the order will be in `FILLED` status. For `MARKET` orders it usually happens immediately but to be sure you need to check the status in response and if it's `NEW` or `PARTIALLY_FILLED` make this call `GET /api/v3/order`.
2. Ok you FILLED your order. In this step, you need to save `executedQty` and `cummulativeQuoteQty` fields. First is how many BTC did you buy, second how many USDT did you spend.
3. I'm not sure what do you exactly mean under "sell only the profit", but lets me guess. You need to take lastPrice of the pair `GET /api/v3/ticker/price` then calculate

`$profit = $currentPrice * $exectuedQty - $cummulativeQuoteQty`.
It will be your profit in USDT. For partially sell you need to make order

```
    'symbol' => 'BTCUSDT', 
    'side' => 'SELL', 
    'type' => 'MARKET', 
    'quoteOrderQty' => $profit, 
    'timestamp' => $timestamp
```

Keep in mind, `quoteOrderQty` can't be less than $10

4. And this is the order for your full close

```
    'symbol' => 'BTCUSDT', 
    'side' => 'SELL', 
    'type' => 'MARKET', 
    'quantity' => $exectuedQty, 
    'timestamp' => $timestamp
```

Comment: Couldn't the profit only be something like `$currentPrice - $priceBought`? Also where in the API does it say about the 10$ rule? I see it applied for the OCO order types, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm using (?).

Comment: You have not priceBought in your response. You need to calculate it. Also, you can make an order in the base or in quote currency quantity. I made it for first (more control), you suggest a second variant (easy to understand).

Comment: $10 rule is from Binance filters. You can read more here https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#filters.
All USDT pairs have a minimal quote size equal $10.

Comment: Thank you Mike, as related here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61582902/python-binance-api-apierrorcode-1013-filter-failure-lot-size I also added a 1-3% margin to the 10$ in order to make sure everything work.

Comment: Hi Mike, I'm having some problems with the "sell everything / close position". When I go to binance I currently have 150~ ADA's available, how can I sell all this quantity? I tried this https://pastebin.com/t87081i8 but gives LOT_SIZE error.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out the reason is the `stepSize` of the coin. So I have to round it, I did `round($quantityAvailable, $adaStepSize)` and it worked. It seems ok to you?

Comment: I don't think that round is a good idea. Better to use floor in this case. The round can give a value that higher than your current currency amount.

Comment: Yeah, I got an error. But my problem is that with the floor I would never actually sell all the quantity I have of ADA, correct? For example I have 150.8824000 ADA, if I use `floor` it will give me 150 ADA, the 0.8824000 wouldn't be sell.

Comment: Found this solution https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api/blob/master/php-binance-api.php (search "roundStep"), seems the most appropriate.

Comment: Yep round step is the best solution. Just never see it inside the PHP lib of Binance.