# Simply put ; is there a better way to obtain a non-rounded decimal

Tags: python, python-2.7

Good day all. Rather than calling the following every time to get ( in this case ) a two place decimal rendition of a float - is there a better ( more pythonic ) way?

```
def dec2( anum ) :
    return( (math.trunc( anum*100))/ 100.0 )
```

Thanks, Al

Comment: See some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383787/round-down-to-2-decimal-in-python      and here    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you are looking for is the built-in `round()` function. You can specify the number of decimal places. In your case, you want two decimal places, so you could simply call `round(anum, 2)`. This is slightly different than what you are doing since you are truncating. The difference is that `math.trunc(5.11999*100))/100.0==5.11` but `round(5.11999,2)==5.12`.

There are some other technicalities on how the rounding works as well that [you can read about](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) if required for what you are doing.

Comment: Had hoped to not round the number at all, but thank you for the response.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no simple way to truncate to a number of decimal places. They all are similar to your method or potentially even more complicated for certain use cases. I feel like this would be a good feature to add to python. Perhaps allow `math.floor` and `math.celing` to take a number of decimal places.