# How to get float to two decimal places without rounding off

Tags: python

Like if I have a 8.225 I want 8.22 not 8.23. DO I have to use it as a string first then convert to float? Or is there a simpler way?

Could not print the decimal without rounding off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round down to 2 decimal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383787/round-down-to-2-decimal-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may take reference from below python function which shall convert a float to 2 decimal places without rounding off:

```
 def round2(x):
     return float(str(x)[:str(x).index('.')+3])
```

Alternatively, You can also convert to int after multiplying by 100 then divide again by 100 :

```
def round_to_2(x):
    return int(x * 100) / 100
```

Usually there wouldn't be any performance difference b/w two unless same operations is repeated millions of times in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

yes . you can use a string for converting.
Like this : `num = '8.225' num = float(num) print(type(num)) print('Float Value =', num)`

I think this code can solve your problem.