# 2 decimal places when using math floor

Tags: python

how can i add 2 decimal when using math floor. So it should be 1.00

I'm not too sure where to add the "{:.2f}".format

```
import math
print(math.floor(1.4))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round down to 2 decimal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383787/round-down-to-2-decimal-in-python)

Comment: you need to manually convert your value to string. `print(f"{math.floor(1.4):.2f}")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a floating number to fixed width in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885663/how-to-format-a-floating-number-to-fixed-width-in-python)

Comment: @Ada They are asking how to print a formatted value, not how to round to two decimal places

Comment: check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) and the following examples

Answer (score 1):

Using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), you would do, e.g.,:

```py
print(f"{math.floor(1.4):.2f}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an f-string.

```
import math
print(f"{math.floor(1.4):.2f}")
```

...or using *str.format*...

```
print("{:.2f}".format(math.floor(1.4)))
```

**Output:**

```
1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `{:.2f}` format formatting to display a number with two decimal places.

Update code:

```py
import math
result = math.floor(1.4)
formatted_result = "{:.2f}".format(result)
print(formatted_result) 
#1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will add 2 decimals after math.floor, it will always be zeroes after the comma: 1.00, 2.00, 3.00 ...
To do so:

```
number = 1.4
floored_number = math.floor(number)
formatted_number = "{:.2f}".format(floored_number)
print(formatted_number)  # This will print 1.00
```

If you want to round it to 2 digits, always to the lower side - you can first multiply your number by 100, then floor it and divide by 100 in the end:

```
number = 1.456
# Multiply by 100, floor to truncate, then divide by 100
lower_rounded_number = math.floor(number * 100) / 100
```

or, the shortcut:

```
number = 1.456
lower_rounded_number = (number * 100) // 1 / 100
```

Good luck!

Comment: using `round` with `float` is dangerous: see _Note_ in the doc. Here an example `round(.675, 2)` -> `0.68` but `round(2.675, 2)`-> `2.67`

Comment: You can test `x = 2.675; (x * 100) // 1 / 100 == round(x, 2)` -> `True` but with `x=.675` is `False`. The reason of that is due to the limitation of the representing floating numbers with fractions

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that, it's really a useful comment