# Truncate decimal places of values within a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, math, truncate

I can `truncate` individual floats using the `truncate` function in `math`. But when trying to pass the same function to a `pandas` `df` column I'm getting an error.

```
import math
import pandas as pd

X = 1.1236

X = math.trunc(1000 * X) / 1000;

#Output
1.123
```

But when using a `pandas` `df`:

```
d = ({
    'X' : [1.1234,1.1235],           
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['X'] = math.trunc(1000 * df['X']) / 1000;
```

Error:

```
df['X'] = math.trunc(1000 * df['X']) / 1000;

TypeError: type Series doesn't define __trunc__ method
```

Comment: Why would you use truncate and not df.round?

Comment: Comparing to other figures with _n_ decimal places. 1.123 billion is a big difference from 1.124 billion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

```
trunc = lambda x: math.trunc(1000 * x) / 1000;

df.applymap(trunc)
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the easiest way to achieve this would be using `.astype(int)`
In your example, it would be:

```
df[x] = ((df[x]*1000).astype(int).astype(float))/1000
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `df['X'] = math.trunc(1000 * df['X']) / 1000;` to `df['X'] =[math.trunc(1000 * val) / 1000 for val in df['X']]`. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is converting it into integer values, like this:

```
df['X'] = df['X'].astype(int)
```