# How to display float numbers to 4 decimal places, without rounding up or down?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to show just 4 decimals of a float, without rounding the number. For example, the answers that I found explain it in a way that the output is rounded up or down;

```
In: 1.23456789
Out: 1.2346
but my desired output is: 1.2345
```

```
from math import sqrt
n = int(input())
list1=[]
for i in range (0,n):
    list1.append(input())

for i in range (0,n):
    print("{0:.4f}".format(sqrt(int(list1[i]))))
```

Comment: As soon as you leave out digits, you are rounding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783897/truncating-floats-in-python

Comment: My personal favorite, assuming `f` is the float number and `trunc` is the number of decimal digists you want to keep: `float(str(f)[:str(f).index('.')+trunc+1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is *truncate*, for example, this is code to truncate `x` to four decimal places.

```
x = 1.23456789
print(int(x * 10000)/10000)
```

You'll still need to format though because you can get some inconsistencies with floating point numbers.

Comment: I think when the number is 1.23400005678 this method only shows 3 decimals instead of 4.

Comment: Yes, you'll still need to format it, e.g. using `"{0:.4f}"`.