# Setting precision in python3

Tags: python-3.x, precision

I want to set precision of a long float number to 2 decimal places. Rounding the number, truncating, floor,etc. won't work. For example my number is 5.196152422706632 . I want it as 5.19 and not 5 or 5.2,etc. I want to simply remove all other digits. How should i do it?

Comment: Use a `Decimal`?

Comment: So is this result returned in a function call, or is it stored in a variable that you need to print? Please post your sample code

Comment: you should refer to this webpage for more help - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/precision-handling-python/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate to three decimals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python)

Comment: See the truncate function in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37697840/14167).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But i have tried all of them. But they seem to round off at some point. That is I don't get desired result every time especially truncate().