# How to trim value to two places after dot without rounding, python

Tags: python, pandas

I am searching for fastest method to get each value in my column with only two digits after dot without using `round()`

`pd.Series:`

input:

```
1.42345
12.33444
111.66777
2.059999
```

expected output:

```
1.42
12.33
111.66
2.05
```

I am thinking to convert it to string and then use `slice` but in slice i need to use start and stop options, its hard when digits before are in different lenght.

If there will be no other option I will use `.str.extract(r'([0-9]{1,5}.[0-9]{2})')` , but maybe there is? some limitations to show float without rounding?

its not duplicate topic, solution from this one is rounding values :[Truncate to three decimals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python)

Comment: Why would you not use `round()`?

Comment: because I need it without round, I need original value trimmed for my own purposes

Comment: @Tabbakhh its not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to take the [`floordiv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.floordiv.html) by `0.01` and to divide again the value by `100`:

```
s.floordiv(0.01).div(100)

0      1.42
1     12.33
2    111.66
3      2.05
dtype: float64
```

---

It clearly performs better than casting to string and extracting up to the second decimal place:

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1_000_000))

%timeit s.astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d{2})')
# 1.76 s ± 42.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit s.floordiv(0.01).div(100)
# 42.1 ms ± 3.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit s//0.01/100
# 40.5 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: thanks, do you think this way is more efficient than .str.extract() ?

Comment: Yes, since that implies dealing with strings which should be much slower @sygneto

Comment: Added the timings @sygneto

Comment: Yes not sure why exactly the diffference in votes, though as timings show both perform just as well @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 0):

Floor div

```
s//0.01/100
0      1.42
1     12.33
2    111.66
3      2.05
Name: dol, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

There are new format specifications, String Format [Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

You can do the same as:

```
"{0:.2f}".format(1.42345) // output 1.42
```

**Note** that the above returns a string. In order to get as float, simply wrap with float(...):

```
float("{0:.2f}".format(1.42345)) // output 1.42
```