# Truncating all values in a file to 6 digits after the decimal in Python

Tags: python, truncate

I have a file that has thousands of values in scientific notation up to 12 digits after the decimal.  I am trying to use Python to truncate all values in this file to 6 digits after the decimal and overwrite the existing file.  Can I just use the decimal package to do this?

```
 from decimal import Decimal as D, ROUND_DOWN

 with open("foo.txt", "a") as f:
    f.D('*').quantize(D('0.000001'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
    f.write("foo.txt")
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate to three decimals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8595973/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to your question:

```
with open("foo.txt", "r+") as f:
    # getting all the lines before erasing everything
    lines = f.readlines()
    #setup for the erasion (idk why it's necessary but it doesn't work without this line)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0) # erasing the content of the file

    for line in lines:
        f.write(f'{float(line):.6f}\n') # truncating the value and appending it to the end of the file
```

This succesfully truncate every number of the file up to 6 decimals (there should be 1 number by line) and overwrites the file.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for