# output float without round in python

Tags: python

i have a problem in python3

my variable is

```
i = 31.807
```

I would transform in this:

```
i = 31.80
```

with two numbers after the decimal point and without round even show 0 in end.

Comment: what do you mean by five numbers after decimal point? your example only has 2 numbers after decimal point

Comment: Sorry
corrected

Comment: You mean truncate? Rounding would yield `31.81`

Comment: yes.  exactly...

Answer (score 0):

**Question: how do I round a float in Python to the desired decimal digit?**

You can use `numpy.round` and supply the value to round and the number of significant digits, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
i = np.round(31.807, 2)
print(i)
```

the output is going to be `31.81`, which differs from you example.

**Question: how do I ceil/floor to the desired decimal digit?**

Unfortunately `numpy.ceil` and `numpy.floor` do not allow for that, so you need to be a bit more crafy:

```
import numpy as np
i = np.floor(31.807*100)/100
print(i)
```

the output is now `31.8`.

**Question: how do I print a number in a specific format?**

Here there is no single write way to go, one possibility is:

```
print("{:.2f}".format(31.8))
```

Output: `31.80`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution from this question here: [stackoverflow.com/a/37697840/5273907](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37697840/5273907) would solve your problem i.e.:

```
import math
def truncate(number, digits) -> float:
    stepper = 10.0 ** digits
    return math.trunc(stepper * number) / stepper
```

When I test it locally with your example I get:

```
>>> truncate(31.807, 2)
    31.8
```