# Python float round error 117.285 round to 117.28 not 117.29

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7, and the code I have is:

```
a = 10.5 * 22.34 / 2.0
print "%.2f" % a
```

and the result I expect is 117.29, but it shows 117.28. How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If Python is using a 64-bit IEEE-754 binary floating point type, then the *exact* value it's using will be

```
117.284999999999996589394868351519107818603515625
```

... and that's obviously lower than the midpoint between 117.28 and 117.29. It's possible that  that's what's going on.

Another option is that Python is using [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

If the exact decimal values matter to you, you might want to consider using [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) instead.

Comment: It is curious...trying the above (v2.6.4), `print a` yields "117.285". Stranger yet, `print "%.4f" % 117.285` yields "117.2850".

Comment: @NathanErnst: Without anything, it's probably using some default precision - and when you specify 4 SF then it *is* 117.2850...

Comment: Python uses platform `double`s for its float type, and the exact value of `117.285` is indeed just below it. (See `'%.18f' % 117.285`.) Python also uses Banker's Rounding, as you can see by comparing `'%.0f' % 0.5` and `'%.0f' % 1.5`.

Answer (score 8):

Mr. Skeet has [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9301754/42346), below is an example of how to use the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module to which he refers:

```
import decimal
a = decimal.Decimal('117.285')
rounded = a.quantize(decimal.Decimal('.01'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
print rounded
# 117.29
repr(rounded)
# "Decimal('117.29')"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple solution and don't care about performance, you could use a function like this to convert to integer, round, and convert back to float:

```
def round_exact(number, decimal_places=0):
    """Round the number to the given number of decimal places by converting to 
    and from integers to avoid floating point error."""
    factor = 10**(decimal_places + 1)
    rounded_int = int(number * factor)
    if rounded_int % 10 >= 5:
        # Round up
        return (int(rounded_int//10) + 1) / float(factor//10)
    # Round down
    return int(rounded_int//10) / float(factor//10)
```

Comment: still valid and still a problem after 10 years