# Why is Python's round so strange?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

My code:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  print (round(1.555, 1))  # It seems normal
  print (round(1.555, 2))  # Why it is not output 1.56?
  print (round(1.556, 2))  # It seems normal
```

Output:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/python$ ./t2.py
  1.6
  1.55
  1.56
  sam@sam:~/code/python$
```

`round(1.555, 1)` outputs `1.6`.

Why doesn't `round(1.555, 2)` output `1.56`?

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly

Comment: In floating point arithmetic in any programming language, you never want to rely on the assumption that a number is **exactly** anything. For the same reason, you should never ask `if x == 2.0`. This is the most important thing to know about floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round):

> **Note** The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected
>   `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal
>   fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See *[Floating
>   Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues)* for more information.

If you keep digging (i.e. click that link), you'll find an example similar to yours:

> The documentation for the built-in `round()` function says that it
>   rounds to the nearest value, rounding ties away from zero. Since the
>   decimal fraction `2.675` is exactly halfway between `2.67` and `2.68`,
>   you might expect the result here to be (a binary approximation to)
>   `2.68`. It’s not, because when the decimal string `2.675` is converted
>   to a binary floating-point number, it’s again replaced with a binary
>   approximation, whose exact value is
>
> ```
> 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875
> ```

String formatting won't fix your problem either. The floating point number just isn't stored the way you'd expect it to be:

```
>>> '{:0.2f}'.format(1.555)
'1.55'
```

This isn't really a "fix", but Python does have a `decimal` module, which is designed for floating point arithmetic:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> n = Decimal('1.555')
>>> round(n, 2)
Decimal('1.56')
```

Answer (score 6):

Straight from the documentation:

> The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example,
>   round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a
>   bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be
>   represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues
>   and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) for more information.

Comment: in other words, when you write 1.555, python might actually be seeing something like 1.554999999999999999999999 and thus the rounding can get weird.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round:

Note

The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using ROUND_CEILING decimal:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_CEILING, ROUND_FLOOR
>>> Decimal(1.555).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_CEILING)
> Decimal('1.56')
>>> Decimal(2.675).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_CEILING)
> Decimal('2.68')
>>> Decimal(2.665).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR)
> Decimal('2.66')
```