# Rounding in Python, but without using int(), if(), round(), ljust(), %, def, or the math module

Tags: python, string, rounding

I'm stuck on a beginner level coding problem. Goal is to round a float number and output an integer. So `x = 3.14159`, output `3` (not `3.0`). We're supposed to be able to do this using only what we've learned, and what we've learned is only 3 functions: `.find`, `<string>[:]`, and converting the given `x = float num` into a string, via `str()`.

How should I be thinking about this? When I write out what logically needs to happen, I always find myself needing `if()`.

I ended up getting partial credit with the following code:
given: `x = 3.14159`

```
x = int(round(x))
print x
```

But I would like to solve it without `int()` or `round()`, or `if()`. My first thought was to use `x[2:3]` and `x[3:4]` to check the tenths and hundredths place values, but to proceed I still run into the `if()` wall.

Comment: I suspect that you're supposed to convert the number to a string, find the period, and then only print the part before that.

Comment: Generally speaking, Convert to string, find the `'.'` character, and slice to that point. If you want more specific help, please [edit] to include a [mcve] showing the code that you've tried so far so that we can give specific answers

Comment: So you're taking a class in How Not To Use Python, basically?  You're being asked to do something that isn't actually a mathematical operation at all.

Comment: While this question doesn't encourage you to take advantage of Python predefined tools, one answer seems to me is to to use a mathematical solution. Another one like others have mentioned to convert to a string. `x = str(x)` then `x.split('.')` which would give you a list of two parts the whole part and the decimal/fractional part.

Comment: Since you are rounding, first add 0.5 to the value before converting to string.  Then just take the characters to the left of the decimal point.

Comment: `if` is not a function btw, you don't need to add parentheses, a way (never actually do this but if it's allowed here, sure) to emulate `if` statement is via using a `while` loop, what you essentially do is the same as with an `if` so like `while condition:` and then at the end you just break out of it immediately meaning it runs exactly once and only if the condition is met

Comment: Do you mean to **round** the number or **truncate** it? What would you do with 2.718?

Comment: Rather than using slicing to try to look at parts of the string and *check* them (which means, you know, `if`), can you think of a way to just take a part of the string **that necessarily** represents an integer? (Hint: can you think of a symbol that's in the string, that can't possibly be in the representation of an integer?)

Comment: Has your teacher taught you about loops yet?  If not, I do hope they mean truncation rather than rounding.  Actually rounding using _only_ those tools is not straightforward for someone new to programming, and requires loops and some tricky code.

Comment: Okay, I went and wrote out most of a solution for rounding non-negative numbers less than 9 without anything other than if/else, for, find, str, and slices, and even that's already trickier than anything I'd give to someone at this stage of learning (I'm not going to link it because honestly it's bad advice; you shouldn't use the programming techniques in it).  I'm pretty sure you were supposed to truncate: that is, just trim off everything after the decimal.

Comment: @RyanM idk, seems like they weren't even allowed to use `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a poorly constructed string manipulation problem because you'd never actually go about solving this problem this way. But using only what you've been taught, you can accomplish the task:

```py
x = 3.14159

# 0.5 (optional?) add 0.5 to x so that it will be properly rounded
#     when removing the digits after the decimal
x += 0.5

# 1. convert the int to a string
x_str = str(x)

# 2. find the index of the decimal point in the string
decimal_idx = x_str.find('.')

# 3. slice the string from the beginning to the decimal
x_int_str = x_str[:decimal_idx]

# 4. do something with the value
print(x_int_str)
```

Comment: @Matiiss Truncation is one type of rounding. There is more than one valid strategy to perform rounding. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14249971/why-is-pythons-round-so-strange

Comment: Incrementing x by 0.5 is not optional. I didn't know that you could add 0.5 to any float number, ignore right of the decimal, and have a rounded integer. So simple!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in string format feature:

```
x = 123.35643
rounded = f'{x:.2f}'
print(rounded)
```

Your output would be: `123.36`

Or to get the whole number:

```
rounded = f'{x:.0f}'
print(rounded)
```

Comment: I'd think that's not something they've learnt yet and the way they are supposed to approach this seems rather clear to me, but sure, this works for a general purpose I guess

Comment: Well he mentioned having to turn it into a string.  This is the only real way to turn it into a string and round in one line.