# Round at two decimals

Tags: python, numpy

```
In [86]: array.std()
Out[86]: 100.70953143681199

In [87]: array.std().round()
Out[87]: 101.0

In [88]: array.std().round(2)
Out[88]: 100.70999999999999

In [89]: array.std().round(decimals=2)
Out[89]: 100.70999999999999

In [90]: np.round(array.std(), decimals=2)
Out[90]: 100.70999999999999
```

I would like to standard deviation to be round at 2 decimals, but it didn't work so far. How could I fix it? How to make that works with `numpy`?

Comment: surround it with `int()`

Comment: If you want to stay in `numpy` you can just add `astype()`, e.g. `array.mean().round().astype(np.int)`

Comment: Why do you want to round the std. dev? Is this purely for display / reporting purposes? If so, you want to use string formatting, not numeric rounding. (And if you want to use the _rounded_ value in further computations, you should be asking yourself why you want to needlessly throw away accuracy for those computations.)

Answer (score 1):

Python has a builtin function called [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round); but to get it how you want, you'll want to cast the `std` to a float. Something like `std_dev = round(float(array.std()), 2)` should get you what you want.

Comment: It works, but I would like to make all my computation with numpy. Why it didn't work with numpy?

Comment: It looks like this question comes up every now and again on SO. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261843/python-np-round-with-decimal-option-larger-than-2#comment33813850_22261843), and the subsequent answer, note that the number to which you are trying to round don't have exact binary equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is properly rounding the numbers in the cases you show, but you are seeing the results of [floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) when the numbers are displayed on screen.  If this loss of precision will truly cause a problem for you then you should consider using the `decimal` package.

```
import decimal
s = decimal.Decimal(100.70953143681199)
s = round(s, 2)
print(s)
# 100.71
```