# How do I round a floating point number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, numbers

I have a changing variable that is a floating point (ex: `2.003`)

And I want to automatically change it to only 2 decimal places.

Comment: have a look at this previous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly

Comment: In calculations, or just for display? Have you looked at [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) function:

```
print round(2.003, 2)   # 2.0
print round(2.013, 2)   # 2.01
```

Otherwise keep the precision and only display the number of decimals you want:

```
print '%.2f' % 2.003    # 2.00
print '%.2f' % 2.013    # 2.01
```

Comment: In my experience, the two-argument form of `round` is very rarely the right thing:  if the user is rounding for display purposes, then he/she should be using string formatting (as you describe).  If the user wants a float because the output will be used for further computation, you have to wonder why it's acceptable to throw out extra accuracy by rounding.  And for monetary applications, `Decimal` is usually the way to go: with binary floating-point, rounding of (binary approximations to) decimal halfway cases, while perfectly well-defined, is essentially arbitrary from a user's point of view.

Comment: See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2012-September/016213.html and the surrounding thread for more ...