# Rounding numbers using the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I'm trying to figure out how to show only one digit after the decimal point in a Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion assignment.  The only one coming up with multiple digits thus far is 13 degrees Celsius, which ends up as 55.400000000000006.  My for statement looks like this.

```
def main():
    for ct in range (0, 21):
        fe = 9 / 5 * (ct) + 32
        print (ct, "Celsius equals", fe, "Fahrenheit")
```

Like I said, the program runs as expected, I just would like to clean that one conversion up.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please tag with relevant tags. You want help with `rounding` in `python`, and your question has nothing to do with `using` or `loops` (or `for-loop`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 1):

```
print("%d Celsius equals %.1f Fahrenheit" % (ct, fe))
# => 13 Celsius equals 55.4 Fahrenheit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python function `round()`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

I believe the proper usage would be `round(fe, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be using Python. To format your code, put four blank spaces before each line so that it is more readable, like this:

```
def main(): 
    for ct in range (0, 21): 
        fe = 9 / 5 * (ct) + 32 
        print (ct, "Celsius equals", fe, "Fahrenheit")
```

If you want to round your answer, use Python's round() function. This would make your print statement something like this: `print (ct, "Celsius equals", round(fe, 1), "Fahrenheit")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def main():
    for ct in range (0, 21):
        fe = 9 / 5 * (ct) + 32
        print(ct, "Celsius equals", (math.ceil(fe*100)/100) , "Fahrenheit")
```

This might work.

Answer (score 0):

You can show one decimal point without having to use another operator like `round` or `math.ceil`. (In python 2.7 this would be)

```
'%.1f' % (5.34)
```

Here are some quirks of using the `round` function that you should be aware of : [round() in Python doesn't seem to be rounding properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly)