# Round number to nearest integer

Tags: python, rounding

I've been trying to round long float numbers like:

```
32.268907563;
32.268907563;
31.2396694215;
33.6206896552;
...
```

With no success so far. I tried `math.ceil(x)`, `math.floor(x)` (although that would round up or down, which is not what I'm looking for) and `round(x)` which didn't work either (still float numbers).

What could I do?

**Code:**

```
for i in widthRange:
    for j in heightRange:
        r, g, b = rgb_im.getpixel((i, j))
        h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0)
        h = h * 360
        int(round(h))
        print(h)
```

Comment: I would try `int(x)`

Comment: would that not give error? invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: @TheBrofessor - `int(x)` does NOT round `x` to the closest integer. Just try `int(0.6)` and you'll see. OP asked about rounding explicitly.

Comment: The OP's example use-case is where the quantity is a positive float, doesn't care about corner-cases, F-P inexactness, and we only need to care about carrying 3 (or maybe 4) decimal places in HSV coords to ultimately get the right integer value for `H * 360`. But many answers here went more general.

Answer (score 541, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

```py
round(x)
```

will round it and change it to integer.

You are not assigning `round(h)` to any variable. When you call `round(h)`, it returns the integer number but does nothing else; you have to change that line for:

```py
h = round(h)
```

to assign the new value to `h`.

---

As @plowman said in the comments, Python's `round()` doesn't work as one would normally expect, and that's because the way the number is stored as a variable is usually not the way you see it on screen. There are [lots of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly#56833) that explain this behavior.

One way to avoid this problem is to use the Decimal as stated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15398691/4345659).

In order for this answer to work properly without using extra libraries it would be convenient to use a custom rounding function. I came up with the following solution, that as far as I tested avoided all the storing issues. It is based on using the string representation, obtained with `repr()` (NOT `str()`!). It looks hacky but it was the only way I found to solve all the cases. It works with both Python2 and Python3.

```
def proper_round(num, dec=0):
    num = str(num)[:str(num).index('.')+dec+2]
    if num[-1]>='5':
        return float(num[:-2-(not dec)]+str(int(num[-2-(not dec)])+1))
    return float(num[:-1])
```

Tests:

```
>>> print(proper_round(1.0005,3))
1.001
>>> print(proper_round(2.0005,3))
2.001
>>> print(proper_round(3.0005,3))
3.001
>>> print(proper_round(4.0005,3))
4.001
>>> print(proper_round(5.0005,3))
5.001
>>> print(proper_round(1.005,2))
1.01
>>> print(proper_round(2.005,2))
2.01
>>> print(proper_round(3.005,2))
3.01
>>> print(proper_round(4.005,2))
4.01
>>> print(proper_round(5.005,2))
5.01
>>> print(proper_round(1.05,1))
1.1
>>> print(proper_round(2.05,1))
2.1
>>> print(proper_round(3.05,1))
3.1
>>> print(proper_round(4.05,1))
4.1
>>> print(proper_round(5.05,1))
5.1
>>> print(proper_round(1.5))
2.0
>>> print(proper_round(2.5))
3.0
>>> print(proper_round(3.5))
4.0
>>> print(proper_round(4.5))
5.0
>>> print(proper_round(5.5))
6.0
>>> 
>>> print(proper_round(1.000499999999,3))
1.0
>>> print(proper_round(2.000499999999,3))
2.0
>>> print(proper_round(3.000499999999,3))
3.0
>>> print(proper_round(4.000499999999,3))
4.0
>>> print(proper_round(5.000499999999,3))
5.0
>>> print(proper_round(1.00499999999,2))
1.0
>>> print(proper_round(2.00499999999,2))
2.0
>>> print(proper_round(3.00499999999,2))
3.0
>>> print(proper_round(4.00499999999,2))
4.0
>>> print(proper_round(5.00499999999,2))
5.0
>>> print(proper_round(1.0499999999,1))
1.0
>>> print(proper_round(2.0499999999,1))
2.0
>>> print(proper_round(3.0499999999,1))
3.0
>>> print(proper_round(4.0499999999,1))
4.0
>>> print(proper_round(5.0499999999,1))
5.0
>>> print(proper_round(1.499999999))
1.0
>>> print(proper_round(2.499999999))
2.0
>>> print(proper_round(3.499999999))
3.0
>>> print(proper_round(4.499999999))
4.0
>>> print(proper_round(5.499999999))
5.0
```

Finally, the corrected answer would be:

```
# Having proper_round defined as previously stated
h = int(proper_round(h))
```

---

**Tests:**

```
>>> proper_round(6.39764125, 2)
6.31 # should be 6.4
>>> proper_round(6.9764125, 1)
6.1  # should be 7
```

The gotcha here is that the `dec`-th decimal can be 9 and if the `dec+1`-th digit >=5 the 9 will become a 0 and a 1 should be carried to the `dec-1`-th digit.

If we take this into consideration, we get:

```py
def proper_round(num, dec=0):
    num = str(num)[:str(num).index('.')+dec+2]
    if num[-1]>='5':
      a = num[:-2-(not dec)]       # integer part
      b = int(num[-2-(not dec)])+1 # decimal part
      return float(a)+b**(-dec+1) if a and b == 10 else float(a+str(b))
    return float(num[:-1])
```

In the situation described above `b = 10` and the previous version would just concatenate `a` and `b` which would result in a concatenation of `10` where the trailing 0 would disappear. This version transforms `b` to the right decimal place based on `dec`, as a proper carry.

Comment: print("4.5)", int(round(4.5)))   # gave me 4
    print("5.5)", int(round(5.5)))   # gave me 6    :,(

Comment: It's related to the Python version. It gives me 5 and 6 using Python 2.7.9 and, as you said, 4 and 6 using Python 3.4.2

Comment: Worth noting: this solution does not round in the way you probably expect. For example, `int(round(4.5))` rounds down to 4 while `int(round(4.500001))` correctly rounds to 5.

Comment: If youn want an integer then `round(x)` is sufficient in Python 3.6.2 (and maybe lower versions as well). The result is already of type int. Note: `round(x, n)` will be of type float.

Comment: This doesn't work for 112439.50093565206. It gives o/p -> 11253.0. Damn weird..!!!!

Comment: I think even with the update this has errors. I get unusual results for `proper_round(0.0005,4)` and `proper_round(0.9995,4)`. I get something even stranger for `proper_round(0.9995,5)`

Comment: proper_round(19.5) gives very wrong answers for both versions of the custom function. for the first version it returns 110.0 and for the second it returns 11.0

Comment: @franciscosollima: I also have problems with `proper_round(169.5)`. The first version yields `1610.0` and the second `26.0`...

Comment: `proper_round(xx9.5)` where xx can be any number or numbers doesn't work. 19.5->11.0, 29.5->12.0, 39.5->13.0, 139.5->23.0.

Comment: @plowman - the round() function uses round-half-to-even (colloquially Banker's Rounding). From the docs - "rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)" https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 29):

Use `round(x, y)`. It will round up your number up to your desired decimal place.

For example:

```
>>> round(32.268907563, 3)
32.269
```

Comment: Using `round(x)` will already return an integer in newer versions of python (`>=3.6`)

Answer (score 25):

`round(value,significantDigit)` is the ordinary solution, however this does not operate as one would expect from a math perspective when round values ending in `5`.  If the `5` is in the digit just after the one you're rounded to, these values are only sometimes rounded up as expected (i.e. `8.005` rounding to two decimal digits gives `8.01`).  For certain values due to the quirks of floating point math, they are rounded down instead!

i.e.

```
>>> round(1.0005,3)
1.0
>>> round(2.0005,3)
2.001
>>> round(3.0005,3)
3.001
>>> round(4.0005,3)
4.0
>>> round(1.005,2)
1.0
>>> round(5.005,2)
5.0
>>> round(6.005,2)
6.0
>>> round(7.005,2)
7.0
>>> round(3.005,2)
3.0
>>> round(8.005,2)
8.01
```

Weird.

Assuming your intent is to do the traditional rounding for statistics in the sciences, this is a handy wrapper to get the `round` function working as expected needing to `import` extra stuff like `Decimal`.

```
>>> round(0.075,2)

0.07

>>> round(0.075+10**(-2*5),2)

0.08
```

Aha! So based on this we can make a function...

```
def roundTraditional(val,digits):
   return round(val+10**(-len(str(val))-1), digits)
```

Basically this adds a value guaranteed to be smaller than the least given digit of the string you're trying to use `round` on. By adding that small quantity it preserve's `round`'s behavior in most cases, while now ensuring if the digit inferior to the one being rounded to is `5` it rounds up, and if it is `4` it rounds down.

The approach of using `10**(-len(val)-1)` was deliberate, as it the largest small number you can add to force the shift, while also ensuring that the value you add never changes the rounding even if the decimal `.` is missing.  I could use just `10**(-len(val))` with a condiditional `if (val>1)` to subtract `1` more... but it's simpler to just always subtract the `1` as that won't change much the applicable range of decimal numbers this workaround can properly handle.  This approach will fail if your values reaches the limits of the type, this will fail, but for nearly the entire range of valid decimal values it should work.

You can also use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library to accomplish this, but the wrapper I propose is simpler and may be preferred in some cases.

---

**Edit:** Thanks [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght) for pointing out that the `5` fringe case occurs only for certain values.  Also an earlier version of this answer wasn't explicit enough that the odd rounding behavior *occurs only when the digit immediately inferior to the digit you're rounding to has a `5`*.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think decimals with `5` as their last digit will always round down. That's not the case in a quick test I just did with numbers like `1.5`, `2.5`, `3.5` and so on and `1.05`, `1.15`, `1.25`, `1.35` rounding to one decimal place. The first set (exact halves rounding to small integers) always round to an even integer. The latter set do not round consistently, probably due to inexact binary representations of some of the values. The floats that have exact binary representations like `1.25` round to have an even least significant digit, but the others appear to round randomly.

Comment: Interesting... you're right.  `round(4.0005,3)` gives `4.0` and `round(1.0005,3)` gives `1.0`, but `round(2.0005,3)` gives `2.001` and  `round(3.0005,3)` gives `3.001`.  But that's precisely why my proposed solution is necessary ... you don't know what to expect from the stock round, on this significant case!

Comment: Thanks for this.  Your function will come in handy when this problem comes up.

Comment: Did you mean to have `, digits` at end of that return statement? No pun intended. (*mean* I mean)

Comment: Ah correct, indeed that should have been in there.  Good catch... surprised nobody else had noticed!  Will save those who utilize the solution some frustration. :-)

Comment: round(2345, -2) --> 2300.0 !

Comment: That's expected ... `round(x, 0)`: round to ones place ; `round(x, -1)` : round to tens place; `round(x, -2)`; round to hundreds place.  Normal round function in your example produces the predictable result.  From my crude testing, I don't see vanilla `round` producing the irregular rounding in values `>= 1`, although it might hit for certain values or for large values.  Premise of method is to add a very small number (negation of the length of input string minus one is somewhat arbitrarily chosen) to ensure the decimal `0.#....#50` cases behave predictably when rounding to the 2nd LSD.

Comment: The answer from stackoverflow.com/a/59774823/866333 nails it for me: `print(Decimal(2.5).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP))`. The batteries included, `Decimal`, is well documented in answers to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior, eg stackoverflow.com/a/52607477/866333.

Comment: This answer is technically correct but very offtopic to the OP's use-case of float rounding in RGB -> HSV conversion. And as to `round(8.005,2)`, it's doing what it's supposed to "round to nearest 2-decimal place FP value", not "round to nearest int". The fact that some floats ending in .005 when rounded by `round(, 2)` round up whereas others round down is just a quirk of F-P representation. Anyway this observation is a duplicate of [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 24):

For positives, try

```
int(x + 0.5)
```

To make it work for negatives too, try

```
int(x + (0.5 if x > 0 else -0.5))
```

`int()` works like a floor function and hence you can exploit this property. This is definitely the fastest way.

Comment: doesn't work for negatives
`>>> x=-0.999`
`>>> int(x), round(x), int(x+0.5)`
`(0, -1.0, 0)`

Comment: If you care about corner cases don't use the "add 0.5 and floor" technique - there are some values that may not round the way you expect! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302585/2732969 for a C++ take and the https://stackoverflow.com/a/38744026/2732969 answer in this very question.

Comment: I needed a fast method, it didn't have to be accurate and wouldn't have many corner cases, and error in corner cases isn't important in my scenario. So this is definitely my go to for some special cases where speed is priority. Don't recommend for precision or accuracy.

Answer (score 16):

Your solution is calling round without specifying the second argument (number of decimal places)

```
>>> round(0.44)
0
>>> round(0.64)
1
```

which is a much better result than

```
>>> int(round(0.44, 2))
0
>>> int(round(0.64, 2))
0
```

From the Python documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

> round(number[, ndigits])
>
> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If
>   ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its
>   input.
>
> Note
>
> The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example,
>   round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a
>   bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be
>   represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues
>   and Limitations for more information.

Answer (score 12):

Isn't just Python doing [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), as prescribed by [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)?

Be careful redefining, or using "non-standard" rounding…

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33019948/109839)

Comment: This answer is a bit unclear. `Round half to even` is absolutely not prescribed by IEEE 754, but is instead only one of several rounding options [described by the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Roundings_to_nearest). `Round to nearest, ties away from zero` (ie the behavior that most people expect) is also an option, and is the default in, for example, C/C++.

Comment: I agree, the wording is quite confusing. What I meant that Python is rounding half to heven (see the table at the end of https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex where `round` is explained) and it is doing so according to the way "round half to even" is prescribed to work (or described) by the standard.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use numpy assuming if you are using python3.x here is an example

```
import numpy as np
x = 2.3
print(np.rint(x))
>>> 2.0
```

Comment: ...or `arr.round()` on a numpy array.

Answer (score 1):

The rationale for rounding a x500... to the even value in the 'x' digit is the correct method and has nothing to do with the binary represntation of the value. It is the 'proper' algorithm to employ. Advanced science classes and statistics classes teach this. But why is this the case?

Minimizing accumulated errors!

When you round a value, you introduce an error value on that term. If you are summing together masses of values and you always round an x500... value up [i.e. to x+1], then you will have an inherent bias to your error accumulation.

On a set of N numbers, where M of those numbers are of the form x500..., a round up methodology will introduce a +ve error term of magnitude M * 0.5 of the digit you are rounding to.

However, if you always round to even, then you have an *expectation* that half of those M error terms are +ve and half are -ve. Therefore, you have the *expecatation* that they will cancel leaving you with a net zero error from those M terms. Isn't an error of 0 a whole lot better than an error of M * 0.5?

But, that net 0 error is only an *expectation*. When you consider flipping a "fair" coin (an analogous problem) such that "heads" = +1 and "tails" = -1, M times, and add up the sum of all flips, there is a statistical expectation of a 0 result, but the magnitude of the "wander" from 0 (could be +ve or -ve) is generally bound by sqrt(M) -- or is it log(M)? haven't cracked open a statistics book in quite some time. The actual answer (sqrt or log) is irrelevant to this question as both sqrt(M) and log(M) are smaller than M for all M>1].

So, as it pertains to our summation of numbers scenario, with M values of the form x500..., since M is finite, we have an *expectation* that the error term from those M values will be zero, but we also have an even stronger *expectation* that the magnitude of the error term ought to be bound by sqrt(M) * 0.5 of the digit you are rounding to.

0 is fantastic, but an *expected* sqrt(M) * 0.5 is still a whole lot better than *guaranteed* M * 0.5.

Yes, you can have a pathological case where you end up with M * 0.5, but such a scenario should be an outlier rather than the norm -- and that rare outlier is no worse than the "always round up" approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you need (for example) a two digit approximation for A, then 
`int(A*100+0.5)/100.0` will do what you are looking for.

If you need three digit approximation multiply and divide by 1000 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I use and may advise the following solution (python3.6):

```
y = int(x + (x % (1 if x >= 0 else -1)))
```

It works fine for half-numbers (positives and negatives) and works even faster than int(round(x)):

```
round_methods = [lambda x: int(round(x)), 
                 lambda x: int(x + (x % (1 if x >= 0 else -1))),
                 lambda x: np.rint(x).astype(int),
                 lambda x: int(proper_round(x))]

for rm in round_methods:
    %timeit rm(112.5)
Out:
201 ns ± 3.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
159 ns ± 0.646 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
925 ns ± 7.66 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.18 µs ± 8.66 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

for rm in round_methods:
    print(rm(112.4), rm(112.5), rm(112.6))
    print(rm(-12.4), rm(-12.5), rm(-12.6))
    print('=' * 11)

Out:
112 112 113
-12 -12 -13
===========
112 113 113
-12 -13 -13
===========
112 112 113
-12 -12 -13
===========
112 113 113
-12 -13 -13
===========
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thing like this should also work

```
import numpy as np    

def proper_round(a):
    '''
    given any real number 'a' returns an integer closest to 'a'
    '''
    a_ceil = np.ceil(a)
    a_floor = np.floor(a)
    if np.abs(a_ceil - a) < np.abs(a_floor - a):
        return int(a_ceil)
    else:
        return int(a_floor)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky, to be honest. There are many simple ways to do this nevertheless. Using `math.ceil()`, `round()`, and `math.floor()`, you can get a `integer` by using for example:

```
n = int(round(n))
```

If before we used this function `n = 5.23`, we would get returned `5`. If you wanted to round to different place values, you could use this function:

```
def Round(n,k):
  point = '%0.' + str(k) + 'f'
  if k == 0:
    return int(point % n)
  else:
    return float(point % n)
```

If we used `n` (`5.23`) again, round it to the nearest tenth, and print the answer to the console, our code would be:

```
Round(5.23,1)
```

Which would return `5.2`. Finally, if you wanted to round something to the nearest, let's say, 1.2, you can use the code:

```
def Round(n,k):
    return k * round(n/k)
```

If we wanted `n` to be rounded to `1.2`, our code would be:

```
print(Round(n,1.2))
```

and our result:

```
4.8
```

Thank you! If you have any questions, please add a comment. :) (Happy Holidays!)

Answer (score 0):

In the correct answer mentioned in this does not work if I use 79.5. It gives an answer of 710, not 80.

```
def proper_round(num, dec=0):
num= int(num*pow(10,dec+1))
lastDigit = (str(num))[-1]
num = int(num/10)
if lastDigit >='5':
    num+=1
return float(num/pow(10,dec))
```

The above mentioned code gives better result

Answer (score 0):

for rounding numbers to the nearest int number, use numpy:

```
p=np.array([     430.15,      57.868,      70.697,      198.13])
p=np.round(p)
```

and the p :

```
array([        430,          58,          71,         198])
```

Comment: try with this data `p = np.array([4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6])`, analyse the outcome and get surprised. you should have read other answers to this question, before posting yours.

Answer (score -2):

For this purpose I would suggest just do the following thing -

```
int(round(x))
```

This will give you nearest integer.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -2):

Click the link for the explanation. The article linked in my post talks all about the code and how to use it.

https://kodify.net/python/math/truncate-decimals/

```py
import math

def truncate(number, decimals=0):
    """
    Returns a value truncated to a specific number of decimal places.
    """
    if not isinstance(decimals, int):
        raise TypeError("decimal places must be an integer.")
    elif decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError("decimal places has to be 0 or more.")
    elif decimals == 0:
        return math.trunc(number)

    factor = 10.0 ** decimals
    return math.trunc(number * factor) / factor
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Comment: Click the link for the explanation. The article linked in my post talks all about it and how to use it.