# How to properly round-up half float numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, rounding, precision

I am facing a strange behavior of the `round()` function:

```
for i in range(1, 15, 2):
    n = i / 2
    print(n, "=>", round(n))
```

This code prints:

```
0.5 => 0
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 2
3.5 => 4
4.5 => 4
5.5 => 6
6.5 => 6
```

I expected the floating values to be always rounded up, but instead, it is rounded to the nearest even number.

Why such behavior, and what is the best way to get the correct result?

I tried to use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fractions.html) but the result is the same.

Comment: can't explain the behaviour of `round()` but you could use `math.ceil()`  if you always want to round up

Comment: @yurib I would like `1.3` to be rounded down to `1`, so I can not use `ceil()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: Many days have passed since I studied error analysis. However If I recall correctly, the rounding of `5*10**-k` depends on the digit preceding it. By rounding up for uneven digits and down for even digits, you get a positive error half the time and an even error half the time (in theory). When you perform many additions, those errors can cancel each-other

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The [*Numeric Types* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-complex) documents this behaviour explicitly:

> `round(x[, n])`
>   *x* rounded to n digits, rounding half to even. If n is omitted, it defaults to 0.

Note the *rounding half to even*. This is also called *bankers rounding*; instead of always rounding up or down (compounding rounding errors), by rounding to the nearest *even* number you average out rounding errors.

If you need more control over the rounding behaviour, use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html), which lets you specify exactly what [rounding strategy should be used](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#rounding-modes).

For example, to round up from half:

```
>>> from decimal import localcontext, Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> with localcontext() as ctx:
...     ctx.rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP
...     for i in range(1, 15, 2):
...         n = Decimal(i) / 2
...         print(n, '=>', n.to_integral_value())
...
0.5 => 1
1.5 => 2
2.5 => 3
3.5 => 4
4.5 => 5
5.5 => 6
6.5 => 7
```

Comment: IEEE 754 rounding half to even is also described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Comment: In your example, is there a benefit to modifying the local context as opposed to just using the `rounding` argument as in: `n.to_integral_value(rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)`?

Comment: @dhobbs: setting the context once is clearer in intent, but from a technical point of view there is no difference.

Answer (score 59):

For example:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

Decimal(1.5).quantize(0, ROUND_HALF_UP)

# This also works for rounding to the integer part:
Decimal(1.5).to_integral_value(rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Answer (score 33):

You can use this:

```
import math
def normal_round(n):
    if n - math.floor(n) < 0.5:
        return math.floor(n)
    return math.ceil(n)
```

It will round number up or down properly.

Comment: Time and time I am shocked there is not internal function like this. I mean, it is not like people nowadays use a lot of numpy and math in python to implement numerical algorithms....

Comment: It does round 'up or down', but unfortunately doesn't work with negative numbers.

Answer (score 28):

`round()` will round either up or down, depending on if the number is even or odd. A simple way to only round up is:

```
int(num + 0.5)
```

If you want this to work properly for negative numbers use:

```
((num > 0) - (num < 0)) * int(abs(num) + 0.5)
```

Note, this can mess up for large numbers or really precise numbers like `5000000000000001.0` and `0.49999999999999994`.

Comment: There are some subtleties that aren't addressed by this solution. E.g., what result does this give if `num = -2.4`?  What about `num = 0.49999999999999994`? `num = 5000000000000001.0`? On a typical machine using IEEE 754 format and semantics, this solution gives the wrong answer for all three of these cases.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson I've updated the post to mention this. Thanks

Comment: Strictly speaking, both 0.49999999999999994 and 5000000000000001.0 are problematic due to precision. In both cases, adding 0.5 causes necessary precision bits to "fall off" the right hand side of the IEEE 754 double (64bit) mantissa (52 fraction bits + implicit 1.0). The first case basically doubles the value, pushing the (set) LSB out, while the second case is so large that the 0.5 is smaller than the existing LSB value. In fact, for 2^52 <= num < 2^53, it will round integers to even (prob. due to math chip rounding 80bit internal back to 64bit output). num >= 2^53 adding 0.5 does nothing.

Answer (score 15):

Why make it so complicated? (**Only works for positive numbers**)

```
def HalfRoundUp(value):
    return int(value + 0.5)
```

You could of course make it into a lambda which would be:

```
HalfRoundUp = lambda value: int(value + 0.5)
```

Unfortunately, this simple answer doesn't work with negative numbers, but it can be fixed with the floor function from math: (**This works for both positive and negative numbers too**)

```
from math import floor
def HalfRoundUp(value):
    return floor(value + 0.5)
```

Comment: Does not add any value to other answers.

Comment: best answer in this page! can't believe python doesn't have built-in solutions.

Comment: @simomo Python's `round()` function _used to_ round up in older versions, but they switched the rounding strategy to half to even in Python 3. It was a deliberate choice because this produces better results. See: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Answer (score 12):

The behavior you are seeing is typical IEEE 754 rounding behavior. If it has to choose between two numbers that are equally different from the input, it always picks the even one. The advantage of this behavior is that the average rounding effect is zero - equally many numbers round up and down. If you round the half way numbers in a consistent direction the rounding will affect the expected value.

The behavior you are seeing is correct if the objective is fair rounding, but that is not always what is needed.

One trick to get the type of rounding you want is to add 0.5 and then take the floor. For example, adding 0.5 to 2.5 gives 3, with floor 3.

Answer (score 12):

Love the [fedor2612](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770410/fedor2612) answer. I expanded it with an optional "decimals" argument for those who want to use this function to round any number of decimals (say for example if you want to round a currency $26.455 to $26.46).

```
import math

def normal_round(n, decimals=0):
    expoN = n * 10 ** decimals
    if abs(expoN) - abs(math.floor(expoN)) < 0.5:
        return math.floor(expoN) / 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(expoN) / 10 ** decimals

oldRounding = round(26.455,2)
newRounding = normal_round(26.455,2)

print(oldRounding)
print(newRounding)
```

Output:

> 26.45
>
> 26.46

Comment: Great function! Never thought I'll face such an issue with rounding 133.125 with 2 digits to 133.13 nor to 133.12 . Thanks, Man!

Answer (score 3):

Short version: use the [decimal module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html). It can represent numbers like 2.675 precisely, unlike Python floats where 2.675 is **really** 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 (exactly). And you can specify the rounding you desire: ROUND_CEILING, ROUND_DOWN, ROUND_FLOOR, ROUND_HALF_DOWN, ROUND_HALF_EVEN, ROUND_HALF_UP, ROUND_UP, and ROUND_05UP are all options.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding to the nearest even number has become common practice in numerical disciplines.  "Rounding up" produces a slight bias towards larger results.

So, from the perspective of the scientific establishment, `round` has the correct behavior.

Comment: Sure, it's the correct way if you are processing measured data, running simulations etc. But it's incorrect, for example, if you would like to calculate grades in school. In Hungary, we have a 5-grade grading system, and an average of 4.5 is rounded up to 5. I used this as an example when teaching my son Python, and I was stunned when round(4.5) gave 5. I had a hard time explaining to him why Python rounding works differently from what he learned in school about rounding...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution.
It will work as normal rounding in excel.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext, ROUND_HALF_UP

round_context = getcontext()
round_context.rounding = ROUND_HALF_UP

def c_round(x, digits, precision=5):
    tmp = round(Decimal(x), precision)
    return float(tmp.__round__(digits))
```

`c_round(0.15, 1) -> 0.2, c_round(0.5, 0) -> 1`

Comment: Anyone wondering about tmp.__round__, see [Python built-in function source code - round()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078627/python-built-in-function-source-code-round) or [Python 3 Decimal rounding half down with ROUND_HALF_UP context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631553/python-3-decimal-rounding-half-down-with-round-half-up-context).

Answer (score 2):

In the question this is basically an issue when dividing a positive integer by 2. The easisest way is `int(n + 0.5)` for individual numbers.

However we cannot apply this to series, therefore what we then can do for example for a pandas dataframe, and without going into loops, is:

```
import numpy as np
df['rounded_division'] = np.where(df['some_integer'] % 2 == 0, round(df['some_integer']/2,0), round((df['some_integer']+1)/2,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

A small addition as the rounding half up with some of the solutions might not work as expected in some cases.

Using the function from above for instance:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
def round_half_up(x: float, num_decimals: int) -> float:
    if num_decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError("Num decimals needs to be at least 0.")
    target_precision = "1." + "0" * num_decimals
    rounded_x = float(Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal(target_precision), ROUND_HALF_UP))
    return rounded_x
round_half_up(1.35, 1)
1.4
round_half_up(4.35, 1)
4.3
```

Where I was expecting `4.4`. What did the trick for me was converting `x` into a string first.

```py
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
def round_half_up(x: float, num_decimals: int) -> float:
    if num_decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError("Num decimals needs to be at least 0.")
    target_precision = "1." + "0" * num_decimals
    rounded_x = float(Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal(target_precision), ROUND_HALF_UP))
    return rounded_x

round_half_up(4.35, 1)
4.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution achieved "school fashion rounding" without using the `decimal` module (which turns out to be slow).

```
def school_round(a_in,n_in):
''' python uses "banking round; while this round 0.05 up" '''
    if (a_in * 10 ** (n_in + 1)) % 10 == 5:
        return round(a_in + 1 / 10 ** (n_in + 1), n_in)
    else:
        return round(a_in, n_in)
```

e.g.

```
print(round(0.005,2)) # 0
print(school_round(0.005,2)) #0.01
```

Answer (score 1):

So just to make sure there is a crystal clear working example here, I wrote a small convenience function

```py
def round_half_up(x: float, num_decimals: int) -> float:
    """Use explicit ROUND HALF UP. See references, for an explanation.

    This is the proper way to round, as taught in school.

    Args:
        x:
        num_decimals:

    Returns:
            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python

    """

    if num_decimals < 0:
        raise ValueError("Num decimals needs to be at least 0.")
    target_precision = "1." + "0" * num_decimals
    rounded_x = float(Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal(target_precision), ROUND_HALF_UP))
    return rounded_x
```

And an appropriate set of test cases

```py
def test_round_half_up():
    x = 1.5
    y = round_half_up(x, 0)
    assert y == 2.0

    y = round_half_up(x, 1)
    assert y == 1.5

    x = 1.25
    y = round_half_up(x, 1)
    assert y == 1.3

    y = round_half_up(x, 2)
    assert y == 1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share my solution to the problem. Using decimal library.

```
import decimal

def round_number(number, decimal_places):
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
    decimal_number = decimal.Decimal(str(number))
    rounded_number = decimal_number.quantize(decimal.Decimal("0." + "0" * decimal_places))
    rounded_float = float(rounded_number)
    return rounded_float
```

Comment: This is exactly what I also came up with, this seems to be the only way to "clean" a number in float format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

for i in range(1, 15, 2):
    n = i / 2
    print(n, "=>", Decimal(str(n)).quantize(Decimal("1"), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
```

Answer (score 0):

## A classical mathematical rounding without any libraries

```
def rd(x,y=0):
''' A classical mathematical rounding by Voznica '''
m = int('1'+'0'*y) # multiplier - how many positions to the right
q = x*m # shift to the right by multiplier
c = int(q) # new number
i = int( (q-c)*10 ) # indicator number on the right
if i >= 5:
    c += 1
return c/m

Compare:

print( round(0.49), round(0.51), round(0.5), round(1.5), round(2.5), round(0.15,1))  # 0  1  0  2  2  0.1

print( rd(0.49), rd(0.51), rd(0.5), rd(1.5), rd(2.5), rd(0.15,1))  # 0  1  1  2  3  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that `round(9.99,0)` rounds to `int=10` and `int(9.99)` rounds to `int=9` brings success:

Goal: Provide lower and higher round number depending on `value`

```
    def get_half_round_numers(self, value):
        """
        Returns dict with upper_half_rn and lower_half_rn
        :param value:
        :return:
        """
        hrns = {}
        if not isinstance(value, float):
            print("Error>Input is not a float. None return.")
            return None

        value = round(value,2)
        whole = int(value) # Rounds 9.99 to 9
        remainder = (value - whole) * 100

        if remainder >= 51:
            hrns['upper_half_rn'] = round(round(value,0),2)  # Rounds 9.99 to 10
            hrns['lower_half_rn'] = round(round(value,0) - 0.5,2)
        else:
            hrns['lower_half_rn'] = round(int(value),2)
            hrns['upper_half_rn'] = round(int(value) + 0.5,2)

        return hrns
```

Some testing:

[image]

yw

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
# round tossing n digits from the end
def my_round(n, toss=1):

    def normal_round(n):
        if isinstance(n, int):
            return n
        intn, dec = str(n).split(".")
        if int(dec[-1]) >= 5:
            if len(dec) == 1:
                return math.ceil(n)
            else:
                return float(intn + "." + str(int(dec[:-1]) + 1))
        else:
            return float(intn + "." + dec[:-1])

    while toss >= 1:
        n = normal_round(n)
        toss -= 1
    return n


for n in [1.25, 7.3576, 30.56]:
    print(my_round(n, 2))

1.0
7.36
31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def round_half_up(x: float) -> int:
    if x < 0:
        return math.trunc(x) if -x % 1 < 0.5 else math.floor(x)
    else:
        return math.trunc(x) if  x % 1 < 0.5 else math.ceil(x)
```

This even works for corner cases like `0.49999999999999994` and `5000000000000001.0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that takes the number of decimal places as an argument.
It also rounds up half decimal.

```
import math
def normal_round(n, decimal_places):
    if int((str(n)[-1])) < 5:
        return round(n, decimal_places)
    return round(n + 10**(-1 * (decimal_places+1)), decimal_places)
```

Test cases:

```
>>> normal_round(5.12465, 4)
5.1247
>>> normal_round(5.12464, 4)
5.1246
>>> normal_round(5.12467, 4)
5.1247
>>> normal_round(5.12463, 4)
5.1246
>>> normal_round(5.1241, 4)
5.1241
>>> normal_round(5.1248, 4)
5.1248
>>> normal_round(5.1248, 3)
5.125
>>> normal_round(5.1242, 3)
5.124
```

Comment: `normal_round(5.124644, 4)` gives 5.1246  but `normal_round(5.124645, 4)` gives 5.1247 It is not a good solution to just check the very last number and then add a small amount at the last decimal place +1, since the last number may be not relevant at all. e.g. `normal_round(0.4000000005, 0)` will look at the 5 and therefore add 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Another similar solution:

```
import decimal

def round_normal(number, digits=0):
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
    return round(decimal.Decimal(str(number)), digits)
```

or if you are going for speed

```
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP

def round_normal(number, digits=0):
    return round(decimal.Decimal(str(number)), digits)
```

if you need a result in float, then put float around the whole part.

---

- Why not using quantize?

It takes longer to construct the string format for quantize.

- Why not use local context?

If you prefer to change the context just locally, you *could* also do:

```
def round_normal(number, digits=0):
    with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
        return round(decimal.Decimal(str(number)), digits)
```

but the time to execute this is again much higher.
same for the abs math.floor else math.ceil solution (a bit more runtime)

---

**So, why is this cast from float to string needed? didn't the other solutions without input -> str -> decimal work faster?**

Yes, it is faster with less conversions, however, as mentioned there is a problem with *some* float numbers. here an example:

```
> a = Decimal(1.125); b = Decimal("1.125"); a == b
True
> a = Decimal(1.255); b = Decimal("1.255"); a == b
False
> a
Decimal('1.25499999999999989341858963598497211933135986328125')
> b
Decimal('1.255')
```

This means that even if we convert to Decimal, if our input is a float and already changed to a close but not fully matching number, then it does not help at all!

Therefore, we can go the approach to convert to str and then to Decimal:

```
> c = Decimal("1.255")
> c
Decimal('1.255')
```

if we just go with the float 1.255 or use this in a Decimal (so it keeps its error), then **the calculation goes wrong!**

Here the example:

```
> round(1.255, 2)
1.25
> round(Decimal(1.255), 2)
Decimal('1.25')
> round(Decimal(str(1.255)), 2)
Decimal('1.26')
```

But keep in mind, the float -> str -> Decimal works, since the string representation of a float has not such a high precision, so the number is kind of rounded.

The solution helps to not need to change number formats in your other code, but cleanest way would be to work with Decimal everywhere! Then there would also no need for those conversions

Answer (score 0):

**No modules to import, simple:**

```
if (a / b) - (a // b) == 0.5:
    c = (a // b) + 1
else:
    c = round(a / b)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
def round(num):
    return round(num + 10**(-9))
```

it will work  since  `num = x.5` will always will  be `x.5 + 0.00...01` in the process which its closer to `x+1` hence the round function will work properly and it will round  `x.5`  to  `x+1`

Comment: Now `x.499999999` will be subject to half-even rounding, and will (half the time, assuming floating point precision issues don't force it one way or the other) get rounded up. That's worse than the initial scenario, as you're now rounding to the more distant number.