# How do I round a number in Python (Thonny)?

Tags: python, rounding

Consider:

```
def välgu_kaugus(aeg):
    kiirus = 300 / 1000
    valem = aeg * kiirus
    return valem
print(välgu_kaugus(float(input("Mitu sekundid kulus välgu nägemiseks müristamise kuulmiseni? "))))
```

This is my little shitty program. When I input 15 it gives me 4.5, but I want it to round 4.5 to 5, but using the `round` command it rounds my 4.5 to 4 for some reason. How can I make it to round to 5?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Comment: The suggested duplicate isn't one, really; the effect the OP is seeing is due to Python 3's round behaviour for halfway cases (i.e., it rounds ties to the nearest even integer), along with the lucky accident that `300 / 1000 * 15` *is* exactly a halfway case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python for more.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round). For example:

```
>>> round(4.5)  # Your number, rounded to ceil value
5.0
>>> round(4.3)  # rounded to floor value
4.0
>>> round(4.7)  # rounded to ceil value
5.0
```

Comment: it rounds 4.5 to 4 for some reason

Comment: @MarekLindvest: For `round(4.5)`, it will give `5`. By the way which python version are you using? Also, on passing `15` to `valgu_kaugus()` returns me `0`, how you got `4.5` ?

Comment: @anonymous: I'm fairly sure that the OP is using Python 3, under which `4.5` does indeed round to `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is to use ceiling.

```
import math
print math.ceil(4.5) // 5
```

Here are some references on how to round a number in python: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/number_round.htm

[How do you round UP a number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356501/how-do-you-round-up-a-number-in-python)