# Round to nearest 0.25 without banker's rounding in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, rounding

I would like to round a series of number like this:

```
0 -> 0
0.1 -> 0
0.125 -> 0.25
0.25 -> 0.25
```

I have heard that I can use round(x*4)/4 to find the nearest 0.25 unit. However, there will be some problems at the boundary with this function

```
0.125 -> 0 (with round(x*4)/4)
```

Is there anyway I can do the above rounding correctly? Thanks

Comment: @coldspeed: Those questions don't handle the rounding mode behavior the questioner is looking for (which appears to be ROUND_HALF_UP).

Comment: @user2357112 The question is not framed well, so I do not really want to reopen it.

Comment: @coldspeed: Looks like it's clearer now, with the new edit.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `decimal` module gives more control over rounding behavior. Particularly, the [`ROUND_HALF_UP`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP) rounding mode rounds to the nearest option when there is a nearest option and rounds away from zero when there's a tie, matching what you want:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> def round_your_way(d):
...     return (d*4).quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)/4
...
>>> round_your_way(Decimal('0.125'))
Decimal('0.25')
>>> round_your_way(Decimal('0.1'))
Decimal('0')
>>> round_your_way(Decimal('0.25'))
Decimal('0.25')
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply multiply by 4, round, then divide by 4.

Comment: @coldspeed: I was not aware this was a duplicate.  Not everyone can be expected to search for every question every time.  I do flag loads of dupes, but can't be expected to see 100% of them.  It's good that you saw it.

Comment: Biting the bullet, this one is on me and not a dupe in fact. Then again, advice still stands... kinda? Anyway, you may need to modify this answer to address OP's question.