# python math result differs from python result and calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x

why does a simple python calculation give a different result than same calculation in PHP or pocket-calculator?

```
tmp = (50.73 / 120) * 20
```

in python3 tmp now is `8.45499999999`
in php and other calculators it leads to `8.455` (without any manual rounding)

my problem here is that i need to round (commercial rounding) the tmp variable with 2 decimal points and this leads in python3 to `8.45` which is not correct. commercially rounded `8.455` would be `8.46`

Comment: It does it properly, it gives more decimal places than a normal calculator as it can calculate it.

Comment: @TommyLawrence thats not the problem, 8.455 is the exact solution, it is not rounded, it is, as Julien suggested, a problem of float math.

Comment: Oh, ok, I'll check out in python to see if It does it on mine to then.

Comment: If you work with currency, you could work with integers for cents instead of floats for dollars.

Comment: @Adirio: and what can i do to get the correct result? i agree that the lower solutions with round do not work in all cases

Comment: @Jack I added a solution that does work.

Comment: @EricDuminil I would suggest working with `decimal.Decimal` if you are working with currencies as working with integer cents may also cause some troubles when divisions give float results that you need to round. `decimal.Decimal` should be always safe.

Comment: The rounding was subtly but noticably changed from python2 to python 3 and dous NOT work now like in other languages and especially not as one might expect!

Answer (score 0):

Please use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html) instead of `float`:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

Decimal("50.73") / Decimal(120) * Decimal(20)
```

If `50.73` is not a value you input, use `decimal.Decimal` to compute it. If it is a number you input from somewhere, just transform it inot string before creating the decimal, as `Decimal(50.73)` will present the same problems as floats.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it works either. see `Decimal(1) / Decimal(3)`

Comment: @EricDuminil It does work. You must set the precission. By default it is 28 decimal places, thats why you are seeing `Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')` but if you need a different one you can specify more with `decimal.getcontext().prec = 7`

Comment: I don't think it can work for every example. There's an infinity of rationals which cannot be represented by decimals.

Comment: Also, you'd need to use [`ROUND_HALF_UP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python) in order to get commercial rounding. It fails with `Decimal(1) / Decimal(8)` otherwise.

Comment: `decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` as you suggested would correct that. It is something you need to do once for all your code so not that big of a problem.

Comment: It's dangerous to set precision to `7` only. `Decimal(23998562) / Decimal(16221)` comes out as `Decimal('1479.475')` instead of `1479.4748782442514`.

Comment: @EricDuminil that depends on the usage. If you are computing euros and you know the highest amount you are going to compute is under a hundred thousand euros, a precission of 7 is all you need with the correct rounding method. What it has to be noticed is that 7 is the precission not the number of decimals. `99 999.99` has a precission of 7.