# Rounding numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How do you round a column to 1dp?

```
df value 
0 0.345
1 0.45
2 0.95
```

Expected Output

```
0.3
0.5
1.0
```

All the below give the wrong answers:

```
df.value.round(1)
df.value.apply(lambda x:round(x,1))
```

Comment: Maybe get some inspiration from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as floating-point operations are concerned, Python behaves like many popular languages including C and Java. Many numbers that can be written easily in decimal notation cannot be expressed exactly in binary floating-point. The decimal value of 0.95 is actually `0.94999999999999996`

To check:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(0.95)
```

Output

```
Decimal('0.9499999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')
```

Here's a useful "normal" rounding function which takes in number n, and returns n to specified decimal places:

```
import math

def normal_round(n, decimal):
    exp = n * 10 ** decimal
    if abs(exp) - abs(math.floor(exp)) < 0.5:
        return math.floor(exp) / 10 ** decimal
    return math.ceil(exp) / 10 ** decimal
```

Original df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0.345, 0.45, 0.95]})
    value
0   0.345
1   0.450
2   0.950
```

code

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: normal_round(x, 1))
```

Output df

```
    value
0   0.3
1   0.5
2   1.0
```

More examples on rounding floating point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95]})
df['value_round'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: round(x, 1))
df['value_normal_round'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: normal_round(x, 1))
```

Output

```
    value   value_round value_normal_round
0   0.15    0.1         0.2
1   0.25    0.2         0.3
2   0.35    0.3         0.4
3   0.45    0.5         0.5
4   0.55    0.6         0.6
5   0.65    0.7         0.7
6   0.75    0.8         0.8
7   0.85    0.8         0.9
8   0.95    0.9         1.0
```