# Why does round(1/2) returns 0 but round(7/2) returns 4 in Python?

Tags: python

Hello I was trying to determine if a element of a given list was part of the second half of the list. For example if it had 7 elements

```
my_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
```

my function would only return True for elements 'e', 'f' and 'g'.

The solution was pretty simple:

```
def fashionably_late(arrivals, name):
    
    return (arrivals.index(name) + 1 > round(len(arrivals)/2))
```

My solution had a bug though because of how rounding works, I just want to understand why

However this behavior from python is perplexing, why is 7/2 (i.e 3.5 ) rounded to 4 the same way as 9/2 (i.e. 4.5) to 4.

```
for i in range(1,11):
    print(i , round(i/2))
​

    1 0
    2 1
    3 2
    4 2
    5 2
    6 3
    7 4
    8 4
    9 4
    10 5

#The way I expect it to work is: 

for i in range(1,11):
    print(i , i//2 + i %2)
​
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 2
5 3
6 3
7 4
8 4
9 5
10 5
```

As a side note I am aware of the `math.ceil()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`, and `round(1.5)` is `2`)

This convention is often called [*statistician's rounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), as it produces more accurate results over large aggregate data (always rounding up on 0.5 increases the average of the data by 0.5, but rounding either way using a consistent rule keeps the mean more consistent, on aggregate)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's weired to me as well, but according to [here](https://www.scaler.com/topics/round-function-in-python/)

> Round() function in Python follows the half to even rounding strategy.
> In this strategy, the number is rounded off to its nearest even
> integer. For example, if we need to round off 7.5, it will be rounded
> off to its nearest even integer that is 8. And 4.5 will be rounded off to its nearest EVEN integer thus 4.

You may try:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(f"{i}/2={i/2} => round{i/2}={round(i/2)}")
```

and you will see:

```
0/2=0.0 => round(0.0)=0
1/2=0.5 => round(0.5)=0
2/2=1.0 => round(1.0)=1
3/2=1.5 => round(1.5)=2
4/2=2.0 => round(2.0)=2
5/2=2.5 => round(2.5)=2
6/2=3.0 => round(3.0)=3
7/2=3.5 => round(3.5)=4
8/2=4.0 => round(4.0)=4
9/2=4.5 => round(4.5)=4
```

For your purpose, you may add a small number epsilon=1e-6 to change the round() behaviour toward to your need:

```
epsilon=1e-6

for i in range(10):
    print(f"round({i/2}+epsilon)={round(epsilon+i/2)}")
```

Then you will have:

```
round(0.0+epsilon)=0
round(0.5+epsilon)=1
round(1.0+epsilon)=1
round(1.5+epsilon)=2
round(2.0+epsilon)=2
round(2.5+epsilon)=3
round(3.0+epsilon)=3
round(3.5+epsilon)=4
round(4.0+epsilon)=4
round(4.5+epsilon)=5
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [How to properly round-up half float numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers).

The issue is caused by the fact that rounding *precisely* 0.5 is slightly arbitrary in math and there are differing opinions on how to do it. Python follows the strategy that prefers to round to even numbers.