# Round a float and convert it to an integer in a Python2 and Python3 compatible manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

For generating Numpy indexes, I need to round a `float` to an `int`.

In Python 2.7, rounding a `float` gives a `float`:

```
>>> round(2.7)
3.0
```

In Python 3.5, an `int` is returned:

```
>>> round(2.7)
3
```

`np.round()` always returns a float.

Is `int(round(2.7))` the canonical approach to round to an integer in a Python 2/3 compatible way?

Comment: Don't know if it's cannonical, but it's what I would do.

Comment: Python 3 returns an integer if a single argument is given.  Otherwise the type matches the type of the first argument.  For example, try `round(2.7, 0)` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(round(2.7))` works for both versions. A similar question but only for Python 2.7 was asked here:
[Python 2.7: round number to nearest integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/python-2-7-round-number-to-nearest-integer)
- so I would use `int(round(x))`