# Strange behavior of the preprocessor g++ in MinGW

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

I have code:

```
   #if _MSC_VER <= 1300 


     float round(float f)
    {
        if (f < 0)
            return ceilf  (f - 0.5);
        else
            return floorf (f + 0.5);
    }
    #endif
```

Lines above should compile only in old version of Visual C++ compiler. 
I compill this code with MinGW compiller. There is no such symbol like _MSC_VER there, and it code doesn't have to compile, because the expression `#if _MSC_VER <= 1300` must equals false. But, it compiles. 
Could somebody explain me why does it happen?

Compile in MinGW is GNU 6.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, on g++ `_MSC_VER` is not defined, as You noted it's Visual C++ specific.

You could try adding the following:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#if _MSC_VER <= 1300

// Your code

#endif
#endif
```

Also, if I'm reading the C++ standard right, the undefined identifier is replaced with 0, so it passes Your conditional and compiles as if You were using that "ancient Visual C++".

Excerpt from **16.1 Conditional inclusion**:

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator
>   have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for true and false, are replaced
>   with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.

Answer (score 0):

If `_MSC_VER` is not defined then the *compiler* will not see any of the code from and including `#if` to and including `#endif`.

Depending on the context, the compiler will see valid source code, and compile it with success. Rest assured that your version of `round` will not form part of the compiled program, although `std::round` might have been implicitly included somewhere.

Finally, there are faults with using an additive constant of `0.5` to engineer a `round` function. See [Why do lots of (old) programs use floor(0.5 + input) instead of round(input)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302544/why-do-lots-of-old-programs-use-floor0-5-input-instead-of-roundinput/47302585#47302585)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link.