# Displaying RAM in a rounded integer as a string, including a suffix "GB"

Tags: c++, winapi

I have 32 GB RAM. The variable `ram_in_gb` returns 31.917182922363281. I want to round it to 31.9. I expect the `buffer` to return `31.9 GB` string. There was an easy way to do that using `wvprintf`, `sprintf` or something like that. I don't remember how I used to do it in the past, so here is my question.

```cpp
// Usage
wchar_t ram[64]{};
get_ram(ram);

bool get_ram(LPWSTR buffer)
{
    auto memory_status{ MEMORYSTATUSEX {} };
    memory_status.dwLength = sizeof MEMORYSTATUSEX;
    const auto result = GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memory_status);

    if (result)
    {
        auto ram_in_gb = static_cast<double>(memory_status.ullTotalPhys) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
        
        wcscpy(buffer, );
    }
        
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Would something like `ram_in_gb = std::round(ram_in_gb * 10.0) / 10.0;` be precise enough for you?

Comment: @Frank, preferrably I want to avoid anything from `std::` for now.

Comment: `int(ram_in_gb * 10.0 + .5)` should be equivalent to `std::round(ram_in_gb * 10.0)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I'm receiving `319` like that. But I want " GB" suffix as well. It's not only the rounding. That's why I mentioned wvprinf. I don't remember which API call exactly it was, but it was easier that way "%.2 GB" or something like that.

Comment: The `/ 10.0` part was left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: 1024 * 1024 * 1024 isn't portable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Fails on at least one edge case in IEEE754, but most people are pretty chilled about that.

Comment: You are probably looking for [`swprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sprintf-sprintf-l-swprintf-swprintf-l-swprintf-l)

Comment: @Bathsheba Wouldn't the parens cause the `1024*1024*1024` to be done as `int` operations and only the result be used as a `double`? Is that still technically non-portable? (genuinely curious here).

Comment: INT_MAX can be as small as 32767. On such a platform, 1073741824 would be a `long` literal. `1024*1024*1024` is always a compile time evaluable constant expression of type `int`. At the time of my writing I think more "things" running C++ and C code have a 16 bit `int` than any other size.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yeah, that much is obvious. I guess I interpreted you referencing IEEE754 as implying that there was something about the floating point behavior of the expression being non-portable. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: A function API taking a writable buffer pointer and not its size is susceptible to buffer overflow. If you had the size you could use `swprintf_s`.

Comment: @Frank: My IEEE754 thing was on the (int)(x + 0.5) standing in for round(x). It's not always true. See my lovely (?!) answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302544/why-do-lots-of-old-programs-use-floor0-5-input-instead-of-roundinput/47302585#47302585

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think so

Comment: @AdrianMole, but it's not MFC.

Comment: @AdrianMole, `ram = 0x008ff628 L"f GB"`. Something is wrong. https://pastebin.com/Rb1Hu7Pk

Comment: @AdrianMole, that's what I wanted! Thank you! Even tho it says it's deprecated and it would be good to be replaced with something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's 'old' and very "C-Style", you can use the [`std::swprintf` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf) for this, using the precision field of the `%lf` format specifier set to 1 (or how ever many decimal places you want to show). You should pass the buffer length as a parameter to your `get_ram()` function, as the `swprintf` call needs that:

```cpp
#include <cwchar> // For swprintf declaration

bool get_ram(LPWSTR buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    auto memory_status{ MEMORYSTATUSEX {} };
    memory_status.dwLength = sizeof MEMORYSTATUSEX;
    const auto result = GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&memory_status);
    if (result)
    {
        auto ram_in_gb = static_cast<double>(memory_status.ullTotalPhys) / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0);      
        swprintf(buffer, buflen, L"%.1lf GB", ram_in_gb); // Use of "1024.0" above avoids integer overflow ^
    }
    return result;
}
```

From the "Format Specifiers" table (the entry for the `f` format) in the above cppreference link:

> *Precision* specifies the exact number of digits to appear after the
> decimal point character. The default precision is 6. In the
> alternative implementation decimal point character is written even if
> no digits follow it. For infinity and not-a-number conversion style
> see notes.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted. It even fixed the deprecation error.