# Problem with numbers and power of numbers

Tags: c++

Problem:

*In a given range (a, b) ( a <= b, 2 <= a, b <= 1000000 ) find all natural numbers that can be expressed in format **x ^ n** ( **x** and **n** are natural numbers ). If there are more than one possibility to present expressed number, present it with a bigger exponential value.*

| U1.txt | Screen |
| --- | --- |
| 40 110 | 49 = 7^2; 64 = 2^6; 81 = 3^4; 100 = 10^2; |

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

int Power(int number, int base);

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    std::ifstream fin("U1.txt");
    fin >> a >> b;
    fin.close();
    
    for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
    {
        int max_power = 0;
        int min_base = 10;
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            int power = Power(i, j);
            if (power > 0)
            {
                if (max_power < power) { max_power = power; }
                if (min_base > j) { min_base = j; }
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found)
        {
            std::cout << i << " = " << min_base << " ^ " << max_power << "; ";
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int Power(int number, int base)
{
    int power = (log(number) / log(base) + 0.5);
    if (pow(base, power) == number)
    {
        return power;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I solved the problem. However, I don't understand few things:

1. How the `int Power(int number, int base)` function works. Why the log function is used? Why after division of two log functions the 0.5 is added? I found the Idea on the Internet.
2. I am not sure if this solution works on all cases. I didn't know what could be the biggest value of the base number so my `for (int j = 2; j <= 10; j++)` loop is going from 2 to 10. If there is a number that base is bigger the solution won't work.

Are there any easier ways to solve this problem?

Comment: The `+ 0.5` is a crude way of implementing `std::round(log(number) / log(base))`. It doesn't always work. Personally I'd avoid any floating point stuff when solving an integer problem.

Comment: The `log(a) / log(b)` (both are some base `c`) is the same as the `log(a)` base `b`. And the addition of the `0.5` is intended to round up when we initiate the `int` variable `power`.

Comment: You could detail that the exponent `n` must be at least equal to 2. Did you write this code ? Moreover, do you have any efficiency constraint?

Comment: There are given no details about exponent `n` in the problem. Yes, I wrote this code myself, but `int Power(int number, int base)` is not my idea. There are no efficiency constrants. This is a problem from one university in my country.

Comment: @rawrex what is the point of rounding value? Shouldn't it be either correct or incorrect using only integer values?

Comment: @user10203585 as has been noted, that's where the troubles will come from - from mixing floats and integers. The `log(a) / log(b)` well may not be an integer.

Comment: Please note that both `pow` and `log` return (and [convert their arguments to](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log)) a `double`, so that the posted code isn't using *only* integer values.

Comment: @rawrex so removing  + 0.5 won't change anything, as I use only integer values?

Comment: @Bob_ Yes, but using these functions should not make any impacts to the results, because either 7 or 7.0 still has to be powered by either 2 or 2.0 to get 49. Am I wrong? Then + 0.5 has no impacts when my input is only natural numbers?

Comment: Except, e.g. `log(1000)/log(10)` may evaluate to a `double` *close* to 3, but less than 3, like `2.9999999999999996` and when you store it in an `int` it's truncated to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

***How does the function work?***

That's something the OP should have asked to the authors of that snippet (assuming it was copied verbatim or close).

The intent seems to check if a whole number `power` exists, such that in combination with the integral arguments `number` and `base` the following equation is satisfied:

> number = base <sup>power</sup>

The function returns it or 0 if it doesn't exist, meaning that `number` is not an integral power of some integral base. To do so,

- it uses a property of the logarithms:

  > n = b<sup>p</sup>
  > log(n) = p log(b)
  > p = log(n) / log(b)
- it **rounds** the number<sup>[1]</sup> to the "closest" integer, to avoid cases where the limited precision of floating-point types and operations would have yield incorrect results in case of a simple truncation.

  In the comments I've already made the example of `std::log(1000)/std::log(10)`, which may produce a `double` result *close* to `3.0`, but *less than* `3.0` (something like 2.9999999999999996). When stored in an `int` it would be truncated to `2`.
- It checks if the number found is the exact power which solve the previous equation, but that comparison has the same problems I mentioned before.

  ```cpp
  pow(base, power) == number  // It compares a double with an int
  ```

Just like `std::log`, `std::pow` returns a `double` value, making all the calculations performed with those functions prone to subtle numerical errors (either by rounding or by accumulation when multiple operations are involved).  It's often preferable to use integral types and operations, if possible, when accuracy (or absolute exactness<sup>[2]</sup>) is needed.

***Is the algorithm correct?***

> I didn't know what could be the biggest value of the base number so my for loop is going from 2 to 10

That's just wrong. One of the constraints of the problem is `b <= 1'000'000`, but the posted solution couldn't find any power greater than 10<sup>2</sup>.

An extimate of the greatest possible base is the square root of said `b`.

***Are there any easier ways to solve this problem?***

Easiness is subjective and we don't know all the requirements and constraints of OP's assignment. I'll describe an alternative solution without posting the code I wrote to test it<sup>[3]</sup>.

OP's code considers *all* the numbers between `a` and `b` checking for every (well, up to 10) base if there exists a whole power.

My proposal uses only integral variables, of a wide enough type, say `long` (any 32-bit integer is enough).

- The outer loop starts from `base = 2` and increments it by one at every step.
- Inside this loop, `exponent` is set to `2` and `value` to `base * base`
- If `value` is greater than `b`, the algorithm stops.
- While `value` is less than `a`, updates it (multiplying it by `base`) and the exponent (it's incremented by one). We need to find the first power of `base` which is greater or equal to `a`.
- While `value` is less than or equal to `b`, store the triplet of variables `value`, `base` and `exponent` in suitable container.

  Consider a `std::map<long, std::pair<long, long>>`, it lets us associate all the `value`s with the corresponding pair of `base` and `exponent`. Also, it could be later traversed to obtain all the values in ascending order.

  The assignment requires, in case of multiple powers, to present only the one with the bigger exponent. In the example, it shows 64 = 2<sup>6</sup>, ignoring 64 = 4<sup>3</sup>. Note the needed one is the one with the *smaller* base, so that it's enough to ignore any further value if it's already present in the map.

  `value` and `exponent` are updated as before.

Note that this algorithm only consider bases up to the square root of `b` (in the outer loop) and the number of iterations of the inner loop is much more limited (with `base = 2`, it would be less than 20, beeing 2<sup>20</sup> > 1'000'000. Greater bases would stop sooner and sooner).

---

[1] See e.g. [Why do lots of (old) programs use floor(0.5 + input) instead of round(input)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302544/why-do-lots-of-old-programs-use-floor0-5-input-instead-of-roundinput)

[2] See e.g. [The most efficient way to implement an integer based power function pow(int, int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int)

[3] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)