# Python always rounding down?

Tags: python, while-loop, rounding-error, rounding

I am trying to finish an assignment and am very close by python is always rounding my answer down instead of up when it's supposed to. 
Here is my code:

```
startingValue = int(input())
RATE = float(input()) /100
TARGET = int(input())
currentValue = startingValue
years = 1

print("Year 0:",'$%s'%(str(int(startingValue)).strip() ))

while years <= TARGET :
  interest = currentValue * RATE
  currentValue += interest
  print ("Year %s:"%(str(years)),'$%s'%(str(int(currentValue)).strip()))
  years += 1
```

Here is what my code outputs:
Year 0: $10000,
Year 1: $10500,
Year 2: $11025,
Year 3: $11576,
Year 4: $12155,
**Year 5: $12762**,
**Year 6: $13400**,
Year 7: $14071,
**Year 8: $14774**,
**Year 9: $15513**,

Here is what is supposed to output:
Year 0: $10000,
Year 1: $10500,
Year 2: $11025,
Year 3: $11576,
Year 4: $12155,
**Year 5: $12763**,
**Year 6: $13401**,
Year 7: $14071,
**Year 8: $14775**,
**Year 9: $15514**,

I need them to match, AKA round up. Someone please help me :(

Comment: Python's `int` rounds down by default. It sounds like you need rounding to nearest integer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer

Comment: Do you need to round up or round it to the closest integer?

Comment: To always round up, use `math.ceil`

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python rounding", you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: I need them to round to the closest

Answer (score 5):

In Python the `int()` constuctor will always round down, eg

```
>>> int(1.7)
1
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int

> If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

If you want to always round up, you need to:

```
>>> import math
>>> int(math.ceil(1.7))
2
```

or rounded to nearest:

```
>>> int(round(1.7))
2
>>> int(round(1.3))
1
```

(see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round ...this builtin returns a float)

Answer (score 0):

Casting to an `int` always *truncates*; imagine it chopping off all the decimal points.

Use `round()` to round to the nearest float whole number. Then use `int()` to convert the float to integer.