# Python : Format specifier(using %) doesn't round properly

Tags: python, rounding

```
print("%.2f" %(22.235))
print("%.2f" %(22.225))

>>>22.23
>>>22.23
```

In the code written above, I rounded 22.235 and 22.225 using '%.2f'

The result I thought was 22.24, 22.23, but both of them were 22.23.

Through Googleing, I learned that Python's rounding rules are different

If the last number is 5, the rule was to make the nearest even number.

But the code I wrote is not following it.

And even when I randomly change the numbers except 5, the rounding value changes irregularly.

I need professional help. Thank you very much.

Comment: "I need professional help." - Dont we all. ;p

Comment: I'll correct the wrong sentence. It means that rounding rules change when I modify numbers except 5.

Comment: `math.floor()` and `math.ceil()` might be what you are looking for... Do you want them rounded up or down?

Comment: The answers to this question might help with regard to python and rounding floating point numbers and why there are issues - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer

Comment: @Craicerjack I'm sorry. I know how to use the Math module. I was working on my teaching materials, and I found this error in the process.
So I thought I had to know and move on.

Comment: Python uses &quot;bankers rounding&quot;, in which the normal (.5 rounds upwards) rule doesn&#39;t always work. This in intentional however, and using Decimal class and/or math - library you can select in which way rounding should be done. Edit: read more: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior&ved=2ahUKEwjYivXkrLHoAhXF86YKHSmrDFoQFjACegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw3vsv16avpWVzqBUmCAjwvJ

Comment: Thanks to the term "banker's rounding" which @JuhaniTakkunen mentioned, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)