# Is there somethig i am doing wrong or is the expected output incorrect?

Tags: python

This is the third question i got from hackerrank's 30 days of code(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-operators/problem)

Task:

Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost.

Sample Input:

12.00

20

8

Note: Be sure to use precise values for your calculations, or you may end up with an incorrectly rounded result!
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMgq2.jpg)

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip = (tip_percent/100) * meal_cost
    tax = (tax_percent/100) * meal_cost
    total_cost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    print(round(int(total_cost)))
```

Above code worked for most of the inputs given from the system expect 1 which was

```
10.25

17

5
```

my code prints 12 but the expected output is 13, my only guess is that the expected output is incorrect

Comment: For the input (10.25,17,5), the total cost is 12.504. When you apply int, it gives you the integer 12. That's why you don't obtain 13 as a result.

Comment: You can find an explanation here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31818069/14280520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the last line of your function definition. When you use `int(total_cost)`, the value is truncated to be parsed into an integer. What you should do is round the value without truncating to an integer like so:

```py
print(round(total_cost))
```

As a note, round also returns an integer, but rounded instead of truncated.