# Round a decimal number in python

Tags: python-3.x, rounding

How can I round this number `838062.5` to `838063` instead of to `838062`, using the `round()` function in Python?

Comment: The round() function rounds values of .5 towards an even integer (Python Docs, n.d. a). So .5 is round up for positive values and round down for negative values. For instance, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) return 0, while round(1.5) gives 2 and round(-1.5) gives -2. This Python behaviour is a bit different from how rounding usually goes. ([from here](https://kodify.net/python/math/round-integers/))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round number to nearest integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round up:

```
import math
print(math.ceil(838062.5)) # prints 838063
```

Comment: what if 838062.4? I solved it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Python documentation for the [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) explains this *interesting* phenomenon:

> If two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`, and `round(1.5)` is `2`).

While you could use floor and ceiling operations, matching the various cases may be a pain. So, I recommend using the `decimal` module, which allows you to always round half-values up.

```py
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> n = decimal.Decimal(838062.5)
>>> n
Decimal('838062.5')
>>> round(n)
838062
```

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was add 0.5 and take the floor value:

```
import math
x = 838062.5 + 0.5
print(math.floor(x))
```