# Python3 pandas dataframe round .5 always up

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round), Python rounds values toward the even choice if the upper and lower rounded values are equally close to the original number.

I want to round values in my `pandas.DataFrame` such that `0.5` is always rounded up.

A way to fix it would be to use the `decimal` module with `Decimal` datatype as described here:
[How to properly round up half float numbers in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33019698/how-to-properly-round-up-half-float-numbers-in-python)

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.5, 1.499999, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5], columns=["orig"])
    df["round"] = df.round()
    print(df)
```

which outputs:

```
       orig  round
0  0.500000    0.0
1  1.499999    1.0
2  1.500000    2.0
3  2.500000    2.0
4  3.500000    4.0
5  4.500000    4.0
6  5.500000    6.0
7  6.500000    6.0
```

I tried to do something like:

```
df["round"] = df["orig"].values.astype(Decimal).round()
```

but this does not work.
Is there a simple and **readable** solution to ensure that `.5` is always rounded up?

**EDIT**

I'm not sure if the links in the comments answer the question.
The solution presented in the links is casting every float to a string and are manipulating the strings which seems ridiculous for large DataFrames. (and is very hard to read/understand). I was hoping there is a simple function to use like in the `decimal` package

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer), could a mod please close this question.

Comment: Can you post some example on how this solves the exact issue I have with Dataframes rounding up on .5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some tiny value to `orig` when the decimal is `0.5`. That guarantees that any integer + 0.5 will always round up to the next integer.

```py
import numpy as np
df['round_up'] = np.round(np.where(df['orig'] % 1 == 0.5,
                                   df['orig'] + 0.1,
                                   df['orig']))
print(df)
       orig  round_up
0  0.500000       1.0
1  1.499999       2.0
2  1.500000       2.0
3  2.500000       3.0
4  3.500000       4.0
5  4.500000       5.0
6  5.500000       6.0
7  6.500000       7.0
```

Comment: I liked your idea with the ``%` operator. I did end up using an approach inspired by your answer that is:  `df["round"] = np.floor(df["orig"])` followed by `df.loc[df["orig"] % 1 >= 0.5, "round"] += 1`

Comment: even nicer: `df["group"] = np.where(df["orig"] % 1 < 0.5, np.floor(df["orig"]), np.ceil(df["orig"]))`

Comment: Great! Yes, that last one is great. You could also try `df['orig'] - np.floor(df['orig'])` to isolate the decimal. This is just a wild guess though, but I have a hunch that `%` may be slower than `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `decimal` module, you could do

```
import decimal
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[0.5, 1.499999, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5], columns=["orig"])

df.orig = df.orig.apply(
  lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x).to_integral_value(rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `.round()` method will round odd unit values up, and even unit values down.

```py
import pandas as pd

point_5_floats = [x + 0.5 for x in range(11)]
s = pd.Series(point_5_floats)
s.round()
```

```
0      0.0
1      2.0
2      2.0
3      4.0
4      4.0
5      6.0
6      6.0
7      8.0
8      8.0
9     10.0
10    10.0
dtype: float64
```

You can just add 0.05 to all values to fix this.

```py
(s + 0.05).round()
```

```
0      1.0
1      2.0
2      3.0
3      4.0
4      5.0
5      6.0
6      7.0
7      8.0
8      9.0
9     10.0
10    11.0
dtype: float64
```