# I want to shorten a decimal number into the digit that I want the decimal number to become in Python

Tags: python

As I said on the title, I have a decimal number such as "1.512411". I want to shorten this decimal number into two digits, I mean it should be "1.51". I searched for it on internet for 2 days but I could find nothing about this. If there is a way to do it, can you explain me how i can do that? If you explain it detailed, I'll be so happy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round number to nearest integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/round-number-to-nearest-integer)

Comment: @cabad oh, I forgot to say in the post! I have already tried this but it does not give me the result that I exactly want from it.

Comment: "Shortening to two digits" is referred to in english as "rounding". This is one of those very common things that if you don't know the right word, is so hard to search. Best of luck! If that doesn't do what you want, please explain why "rounding" doesn't give the result you want.

Comment: You mean two decimal digits? Rounding or truncating?

Comment: Sounds like multiplying by 100, then rounding to integer and dividing by 100 should do the trick. And if you worry about floating point precision issues, maybe use Decimals?

Comment: I guess it is truncating.

Comment: @Bugra Pakir if the number was 2.3456, would you want to see "2.34" (truncating) or "2.35" (rounding)?

Comment: If you want the result as a string you can use `"{:.2f}".format(number)`

Comment: @slothrop yeah I wanna see "2.34", it's truncating I guess. I'm so sorry for using incorrect word. My native language is not English.

Comment: @mousetail I've never seen this structure. Can you explain me how it exactly does or send me a video about this?

Comment: @BugraPakir More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#format)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Decimals format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389846/python-decimals-format)

Comment: @mousetail I solved the problem thanks to you. By doing "{:.2f}".format(number)

Comment: @Bugra Pakir be careful - that does rounding not truncation.  For example `"{:.2f}".format(2.3456)` gives `2.35`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do this, using the function `round(value, n_digits)` function. This is the corresponding [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Behavior:

```
[In]  round(1.512411, 2)
[Out] 1.51
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`round(number[, digits])`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round) function.

```py
>>> round(1.512411, 2)
1.51
>>> round(1.515, 2)
1.51
>>> round(1.516, 2)
1.52
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using F-String. You guys need to do for truncating the decimal numbers:

```
a = 1.516171
print(f"{a:.2f}") # You need to type the number which you want to truncate.
```

Comment: This does rounding rather than truncation.  For example if a=2.3456, this will print `2.35` not the `2.34` that you want.  In fact, even for your example here, it gives you `1.52` (rounded) not `1.51` (truncated).