# Python rounding variable when printing

Tags: python

I'm new to python so sorry if I word my question improperly but bear with me. So basically I am making a program to calculate the odds of randomly generating the chosen sides of a (x) sided dice. Problem is when I try to print the variable "idealProb", it seems to rounds down to 0 unless its 100% probability, however in the debugger it says the actual decimal it is only when it prints into the terminal that is gets messed up.

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

rolls = []
sides = []
x = 1

totalSides = int(input("How many sides do you want this die to have?"))
clear()

numSides = int(input("How many of those sides are you trying to land on?"))
nS = numSides

while numSides >= 1:
    clear()
    s = int(input("Possibility %i:" %(x)))
    sides.append(s)
    numSides -= 1
    x += 1

idealProb = nS / totalSides

print("Ideal probability: %i" %(idealProb))
```

P.S. Any other comments on my code, any advice on how to make it less messy or a easier way to do what I'm doing please let me know I am fairly new to Python and coding in general, as Python is my first language. Thank you so much for all the help!

Comment: It's the `%i` that explicitly instructs Python to make an integer representation. Try something like `%f` instead.

Comment: or just use `f"Ideal probability: {idealProb}"` (which is new in Python 3.6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [round() in Python doesn't seem to be rounding properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly)

Answer (score 1):

When you write %i I'm the print command you explicitly tell Python to truncate the value to an integer. Read this http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line to output `idealProb` as a floating point number by using `%f` instead of as an integer with `%i` as you have it. That would make the last line:

```
print("Ideal probability: %f" %(idealProb))
```

See the [string format documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) for more details.