# Exact Value after Floating point not rounding up

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to select exact value after floating point but the result is always rounding up. Suppose i have a variable

```
x=12.77888799
```

when i try to format it with

```
"{0:.2f}".format(x)
```

it is rounding up as output :

```
'12.78'
```

I want the output not rounding up:

```
12.77
```

I am really new trying every possible function but stuck there. I am using python 2.7

Comment: So you want to truncate?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly). The `decimal` module might come in handy.