# In Python 3, how do I round a floating point number up to a certain decimal place?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 12.5, and I want to convert it to 13. How can I do this in Python 3?

The task was like this - "Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost"

I solved the problem in Python 3 and in 3 test cases, it shows that my code is working. but in 1 case it is not.

Where,

Sample input:

12.00

20

8

Expected output:

13

And my output was 12.5

How on earth I can take 12.5 as 13?

```
mealcost = float(input()) 
tippercent = float(input()) 
taxpercent = float(input())  

tippercent = mealcost * (tippercent / 100)  
taxpercent = mealcost * (taxpercent / 100) 

totalcost = float( mealcost + tippercent + taxpercent)  
print(totalcost)
```

Comment: Please google "python round".

Comment: Use the built-in function round(value[,ndigits]) see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round

Comment: That makes no sense - $12 base cost with 20% tip and 8% tax works out to $15.36 (assuming tip and tax are both calculated from the base cost). Neither 13 nor 12.5 is correct.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-in-python-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly

Comment: Please use code formating...

Answer (score 1):

Use `round()`

```
print(round(12.5))
>>> 13.0
```

Comment: You forgot the optional ndigits parameter see https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round

Comment: `round` will round 12.5 to 12 on Python 3.

Answer (score -2):

### To round to the nearest X (ie nearest 20.0)

1. just divide by the value you want to round to
2. then `round` the result
3. then multiply it by the number you want to round to and cast to an int

for example

```
round_to_nearest = 20
for a_num in [9,15,22,32,35,66,98]:
    rounded = int(round(a_num/round_to_nearest)*round_to_nearest)
    print("{a_num} rounded = ".format(a_num=a_num,r=rounded))
```

### to just round

oh nevermind it looks like you just want

```
print(round(12.3),round(12.6)) # 12, 13
```

if `round` rounds wrongly (ie [round(12.5) => 12 in python3](https://repl.it/repls/EffectiveDisastrousInitialization)) you can just add 0.5 to your number and floor it

```
int(12.5+0.5)
```

Comment: Round() does all this, without you typing so much

Comment: the OP didn’t mention rounding to the nearest 20. Read the title of the question.

Comment: Nearest 20?!?!?

Comment: just `round(12.5)`