# Rounding a float column to 2 decimal places in python

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I am using databricks and am trying to round a pandas dataframe column to 2 dp. Using existing posts on S/O [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820/round-doesnt-seem-to-be-rounding-properly)] and [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)], I tried the following code:

```
#=========== Solution 1 ==============#

df['value'] = round(df['value'], 2)

#=========== Solution 2 ==============#

def round_and_format(x):
  from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP
  return float(Decimal(str(x)).quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP))

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(round_and_format)

#=========== Solution 3 ==============#

df['value'] = (df['value']*100).astype(int)/100
```

Unfortunately when looking at the SQL DB, the above code does not work properly. As an example **0.916147589683533** is rounded to **0.920000016689301**. The expected value should be **0.92**.

My questions are:

- Is there an obvious error I am making here?
- Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've closed the question as a duplicate, though it's not clear if you want to just display the rounded values or actually keep them, so I've added a bunch of links to cover all the bases. Also note that some of the questions are about vanilla Python which only has one float type while Pandas has several, and you seem to be using 32-bit.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post and provided more details.

Comment: Sorry, what are you still confused about? Did you read everything I linked? No offense but it looks like you just skimmed the code and didn't read any of the explanations. The result you're seeing is due to floating-point rounding error. `np.float32(0.920000016689301) == np.float32(0.92)`. How to handle that depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. In that case, how should np.float(0.92) be handled if I want to return 0.92?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: How can I keep only two decimal places in df['value']?

Comment: Like I said, that depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Do you just want to *display* two decimal points or do you want to save them? If you want to save them, what format do you want to use? Cause float32 apparently isn't precise enough.

Comment: I am saving it to an SQL database.